# Get the data received in a Flask request

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I want to be able to get the data sent to my Flask app. I've tried accessing `request.data` but it is an empty string. How do you access request data?

```py
from flask import request

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_request():
    data = request.data  # data is empty
    # need posted data here
```

---

The answer to this question led me to ask [Get raw POST body in Python Flask regardless of Content-Type header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10999990) next, which is about getting the raw data rather than the parsed data.

Answer (score 2204, accepted):

The [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request) describe the attributes available on the `request` object (`from flask import request`) during a request. In most common cases `request.data` will be empty because it's used as a fallback:

> `request.data` Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a mimetype Flask does not handle.

- [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.args): the key/value pairs in the URL query string
- [`request.form`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.form): the key/value pairs in the body, from a HTML post form, or JavaScript request that isn't JSON encoded
- [`request.files`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.files): the files in the body, which Flask keeps separate from `form`. HTML forms must use `enctype=multipart/form-data` or files will not be uploaded.
- [`request.values`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.values): combined `args` and `form`, preferring `args` if keys overlap
- [`request.json`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.json): parsed JSON data. The request must have the `application/json` content type, or use [`request.get_json(force=True)`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.get_json) to ignore the content type.

All of these are [`MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) instances (except for `json`). You can access values using:

- `request.form['name']`: use indexing if you know the key exists
- `request.form.get('name')`: use `get` if the key might not exist
- `request.form.getlist('name')`: use `getlist` if the key is sent multiple times and you want a list of values. `get` only returns the first value.

Comment: I find that both `request.data` and `request.json` are populated when `Content-Type` is set to `application/json` in the request. Hence, it looks like it is more than a fallback and is populated by Flask even with mimetypes that it does handle. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 304):

For URL query parameters, use `request.args`.

```
search = request.args.get("search")
page = request.args.get("page")
```

For posted form input, use `request.form`.

```
email = request.form.get('email')
password = request.form.get('password')
```

For JSON posted with content type `application/json`, use [`request.get_json()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.get_json).

```
data = request.get_json()
```

Answer (score 276):

To get the raw data, use [`request.data`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.data). This only works if it couldn't be parsed as form data, otherwise it will be empty and `request.form` will have the parsed data.

```
from flask import request
request.data
```

Comment: This behavior has changed now since I am finding that `request.data` does have the raw data even if it is form data

Answer (score 173):

Here's an example of parsing posted JSON data and echoing it back.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST']) 
def foo():
    data = request.json
    return jsonify(data)
```

To post JSON with curl:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"userId":"1", "username": "fizz bizz"}' http://localhost:5000/foo
```

Or to use Postman:

[image: using postman to post JSON]

Answer (score 89):

To get the raw post body regardless of the content type, use `request.get_data()`. If you use `request.data`, it calls `request.get_data(parse_form_data=True)`, which will populate the `request.form` `MultiDict` and leave `data` empty.

Comment: This should really be upvoted more. We can just request.get_data() regardless of whether we received form or json data.

Comment: I was looking for this solution

Comment: Using `request.get_data()` doesn't work for me when `request.method == 'GET':`  I found that `request.args` worked.

Comment: @BradGrissom That's because query strings would never be in `request.data`; the query string is part of the URL and not the entity body.

Comment: This solution works, and if you need the data in string format you can use request.get_data().decode("utf-8") to convert the bytes to string.

Answer (score 57):

If you post JSON with content type `application/json`, use `request.get_json()` to get it in Flask. If the content type is not correct, `None` is returned. If the data is not JSON, an error is raised.

```
@app.route("/something", methods=["POST"])
def do_something():
    data = request.get_json()
```

Answer (score 39):

To get `request.form` as a normal dictionary , use `request.form.to_dict(flat=False)`.

To return JSON data for an API, pass it to `jsonify`.

This example returns form data as JSON data.

```py
@app.route('/form_to_json', methods=['POST'])
def form_to_json():
    data = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
    return jsonify(data)
```

Here's an example of POST form data with curl, returning as JSON:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/data -d "name=ivanleoncz&role=Software Developer"
{
  "name": "ivanleoncz", 
  "role": "Software Developer"
}
```

Answer (score 31):

You can get request data from

1. `request.form` for form data, this includes form and file data,
2. `request.json` and `request.get_json` for JSON data
3. `request.headers` for headers
4. `request.args` to get query params

They're all like a dictionary, use `request.form['name']` if you know the key exists, or `request.form.get('name')` if it is optional.

Answer (score 27):

Use `request.get_json()` to get posted JSON data.

```
data = request.get_json()
name = data.get('name', '')
```

Use `request.form` to get data when submitting a form with the POST method.

```
name = request.form.get('name', '')
```

Use `request.args` to get data passed in the query string of the URL, like when submitting a form with the GET method.

```
request.args.get("name", "")
```

`request.form` etc. are dict-like, use the `get` method to get a value with a default if it wasn't passed.

Answer (score 26):

Import request:

```
from flask import request
```

URL query parameters:

```
name = request.args.get("name")
age = request.args.get("age")
```

Form Input:

```
name = request.form.get('name')
age = request.form.get('age')
```

OR (use indexing if you know the key exists, **specify the name of input fields**)

```
name = request.form['name']
age = request.form['age']
```

JSON Data (for content type **application/json**)

```
data = request.get_json()
```

Answer (score 21):

To get JSON posted without the `application/json` content type, use `request.get_json(force=True)`.

```
@app.route('/process_data', methods=['POST'])
def process_data():
    req_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    language = req_data['language']
    return 'The language value is: {}'.format(language)
```

Comment: I was facing this issue, didn't send "application/json" in headres while calling the API

Answer (score 18):

To post JSON with jQuery in JavaScript, use `JSON.stringify` to dump the data, and set the content type to `application/json`.

```js
var value_data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/process',
    data: JSON.stringify(value_data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response_data) {
        alert("success");
    }   
});
```

Parse it in Flask with `request.get_json()`.

```py
data = request.get_json()
```

Answer (score 16):

The raw data is passed in to the Flask application from the WSGI server as `request.stream`. The length of the stream is in the `Content-Length` header.

```
length = request.headers["Content-Length"]
data = request.stream.read(length)
```

It is usually safer to use `request.get_data()` instead.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an example of posting form data to add a user to a database. Check `request.method == "POST"` to check if the form was submitted. Use keys from `request.form` to get the form data. Render an HTML template with a `<form>` otherwise. The fields in the form should have `name` attributes that match the keys in `request.form`.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/user/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_user():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User(
            username=request.form["username"],
            email=request.form["email"],
        )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    return render_template("add_user.html")
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 12):

To parse JSON, use `request.get_json()`.

```
@app.route("/something", methods=["POST"])
def do_something():
    result = handle(request.get_json())
    return jsonify(data=result)
```

Answer (score 12):

If the body is recognized as form data, it will be in `request.form`. If it's JSON, it will be in `request.get_json()`. Otherwise the raw data will be in `request.data`. If you're not sure how data will be submitted, you can use an `or` chain to get the first one with data.

```py
def get_request_data():
    return (
        request.args
        or request.form
        or request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)
        or request.data
    )
```

`request.args` contains args parsed from the query string, regardless of what was in the body, so you would remove that from `get_request_data()` if both it and a body should data at  the same time.

Answer (score 12):

When writing a Slack bot, which is supposed to send JSON data, I got a payload where the `Content-Type` was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I tried `request.get_json()` and it didn't work.

```
@app.route('/process_data', methods=['POST'])
def process_data():
   req_data = request.get_json(force=True)
```

Instead I used `request.form` to get the form data field that *contained* JSON, then loaded that.

```
from flask import json

@ app.route('/slack/request_handler', methods=['POST'])
def request_handler():
   req_data = json.loads(request.form["payload"])
```

Answer (score 10):

If the content type is recognized as form data, `request.data` will parse that into `request.form` and return an empty string.

To get the raw data regardless of content type, call [`request.get_data()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.get_data). `request.data` calls `get_data(parse_form_data=True)`, while the default is `False` if you call it directly.

Answer (score 6):

```
@app.route('/addData', methods=['POST'])
def add_data():
     data_in = mongo.db.Data
     id = request.values.get("id")
     name = request.values.get("name")
     newuser = {'id' : id, 'name' : name}
     if voter.find({'id' : id, 'name' : name}).count() > 0:
            return "Data Exists"
     else:
            data_in.insert(newuser)
            return "Data Added"
```

Answer (score 5):

When posting form data with an HTML form, be sure the `input` tags have `name` attributes, otherwise they won't be present in `request.form`.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print(request.form)
    return """
<form method="post">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text" id="txt2">
    <input type="text" name="txt3" id="txt3">  
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""
```

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('txt3', 'text 3')])
```

Only the `txt3` input had a `name`, so it's the only key present in `request.form`.

Answer (score 1):

To get form data, try this, The request object allows us to get access to the data that come from a request. it can also help us access other information about a request. Hope that helps. :)

```
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get('/')
def index():
  json_data = request.get_json() #this will get the json data and return a dictionary containing the data sent
  
  form_data = request.form #this will get the form data return a dictionary of the data submitted in a form


  #such can be accessed in the following way
   username = json_data.get('username')
   email = form_data.get('email') # this will be value from the email input
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 json_data = request.form or request.get_json()
 data = dict(json_data)
```

It'll get both the form and JSON data together and convert it into the dictionary

Answer (score -2):

I just faced the same need. I have to save information in case of any unexpected situation. So, I use the following formula:

```
Info = "%s/%s/%s" % (request.remote_addr, repr(request), repr(session))
```

repr(request) will give a string representation of the basic information. You could add user-agent data with:
request.headers.get('User-Agent')

I also save the session continent as it could contain valuable information

Answer (score -3):

```
request.data
```

This is great to use but remember that it comes in as a string and will need iterated through.

Comment: Already answered a lot of times, besides iterating over a string makes no sense.

Answer (score -4):

Try - >

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_request():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       data = request.form.get('data')
```