# Get raw POST body in Python Flask regardless of Content-Type header

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Previously, I asked [How to get data received in Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434599) because `request.data` was empty. The answer explained that `request.data` is the raw post body, but will be empty if form data is parsed.  How can I get the raw post body unconditionally?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def parse_request():
    data = request.data  # empty in some cases
    # always need raw data here, not parsed form data
```

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Use [`request.get_data()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request.get_data) to get the raw data, regardless of content type. The data is cached and you can subsequently access `request.data`, `request.json`, `request.form` at will.

If you access `request.data` first, it will call `get_data` with an argument to parse form data first. If the request has a form content type (`multipart/form-data`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or `application/x-url-encoded`) then the raw data will be consumed. `request.data` and `request.json` will appear empty in this case.

Answer (score 46):

[`request.stream`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request.stream) is the stream of raw data passed to the application by the WSGI server. No parsing is done when reading it, although you usually want `request.get_data()` instead.

```
data = request.stream.read()
```

The stream will be empty if it was previously read by `request.data` or another attribute.

Answer (score 19):

I created a WSGI middleware that stores the raw body from the `environ['wsgi.input']` stream. I saved the value in the WSGI environ so I could access it from `request.environ['body_copy']` within my app.

This isn't necessary in Werkzeug or Flask, as `request.get_data()` will get the raw data regardless of content type, but with better handling of HTTP and WSGI behavior.

This reads the entire body into memory, which will be an issue if for example a large file is posted. This won't read anything if the `Content-Length` header is missing, so it won't handle streaming requests.

```py
from io import BytesIO

class WSGICopyBody(object):
    def __init__(self, application):
        self.application = application

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        length = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH') or 0)
        body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(length)
        environ['body_copy'] = body
        # replace the stream since it was exhausted by read()
        environ['wsgi.input'] = BytesIO(body)
        return self.application(environ, start_response)

app.wsgi_app = WSGICopyBody(app.wsgi_app)
```

```py
request.environ['body_copy']
```

Answer (score 13):

`request.data` will be empty if `request.headers["Content-Type"]` is recognized as form data, which will be parsed into `request.form`. To get the raw data regardless of content type, use `request.get_data()`.

`request.data` calls `request.get_data(parse_form_data=True)`, which results in the different behavior for form data.