# Get raw data from POST request in Flask

Tags: http, post, request, flask

How can I get the raw data from a POST request in Flask?

I am moving from web.py to Flask and have some clients in production that unfortunately are using the content-type header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so changing the header value of the request is not an option (unless it is overwritten on the server).

I cannot use:

```
data = request.form.keys()[0]
```

Because occasionally the `'&'` character shows up in my data and trying to loop through the form.keys adding the `'&'` seems to corrupt the data for some reason.

I'm currently using the solution proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999990/python-flask-how-to-get-whole-raw-post-body), but I'm not too sure if this has any performance issues.

I'm looking for one of three things:

1. Confirmation that the `WGSICopyBody` method won't have any adverse performance issues
2. Ability to make this (`data = request.form.keys()[0]`) method work by looping through the keys and properly restoring the `'&'` in the data
3. Another solution to the problem, possibly by subclassing the `Request` class?