# logging flask post request body

Tags: python, logging, flask

I'm trying to log post requests body on a flask app, like so:

```
app.logger.error("BODY: %s" % request.data )
```

I do this because I suspect sometimes I get a malformed JSON object on the POST. The problem I'm seeing is that the logs contain a truncated request body - it just seems cut in the middle..

I can't put a log excerpt because it's sensitive data.. 
Why is the request truncated? 
Am I doing this wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get raw POST body in Python Flask regardless of Content-Type header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999990/get-raw-post-body-in-python-flask-regardless-of-content-type-header)

Comment: @jonafato - how is this a duplicate? This has nothing to do with content type, which is always application/json.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `app.logger.error("BODY: %s" % request.get_data())`