# How to get the incoming caller's phone number in Twilio Flask App?

Tags: twilio

I want to print/get the incoming caller number in Twilio Flask app. I was referring to the twilio-ivr-phone-tree for this. I tried `print(request.args)` in the `welcome` function i.e the first method which is invoked when I receive an incoming call. But it prints an empty `ImmutableMultiDict([])`.

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*To -ve voters, post a comment for doing so. It helps to increase the quality of the question and make stack a better place.*

Comment: Have you configured Number for incoming: webhook properly, recheck **HttpGet/HttpPost** [ImageLink](https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.twilio.prod.twilio-docs/images/ivr-webhook.width-800.png)

and as you mentioned `welcome()` func is invoked, check if there are any error [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger?quickDate=24)

Comment: @Chenna, request.get_data() is what I wanted. Thanks for your efforts. For more details on empty  dict, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999990/get-raw-post-body-in-python-flask-regardless-of-content-type-header

Comment: If that has solved your problem close the question

Comment: @Chenna I guess you know that you cannot accept your own answer before a certain time. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the Twilio request has a form content type and the raw data will be consumed leading it to appear empty as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999990/get-raw-post-body-in-python-flask-regardless-of-content-type-header).

However `request.get_data()` can print the whole POST and you can easily find that the key `From` holds the caller's phone number.

So, to access it you need `request.form['From']` and it fetches the caller's number to the local environment.

Answer (score 1):

The incoming call request information can be obtained in a Flask app using request.values

these are they keys of the diction returned: 
atts = ('AccountSid',
        'ApiVersion',
        'CallSid',
        'CallStatus',
        'Called',
        'CalledCity',
        'CalledCountry',
        'CalledState',
        'CalledZip',
        'Caller',
        'CallerCity',
        'CallerCountry',
        'CallerState',
        'CallerZip',
        'Direction',
        'From',
        'FromCity',
        'FromCountry',
        'FromState',
        'FromZip',
        'To',
        'ToCity',
        'ToCountry',
        'ToState',
        'ToZip')