# How to get raw request payload in Flask/Connexion?

Tags: python, flask, post, connexion, x-www-form-urlencoded

I need to get the body of a `POST` request with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in a [Connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) API handler. The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10999990/244297) suggests to use `request.get_data()`, however this always returns just `b''` for me. My guess is that Connexion parses the data before `request.get_data()` gets called and that is causing the issue.

How do I get the raw request payload in this case? If there's no way to get it directly, how do I properly reconstruct it from `request.form` (which seems to contain the parsed data)?

Comment: Have you tried use `connexion.request.json` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an easier way, but this seems to do the trick:

```
import urllib.parse

form_data = request.form
request_data = '&'.join([k + '=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(v) for k, v in form_data.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from connexion import request

type(request.form)
# <class 'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict'>
print(dict(request.form))
```