# adding an auth check to github webhooks using flask + python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, github, webhooks

I've been trying to add auth to github but for some reason my hashes don't match,

here is my code:

```py
@app.route('/update', methods=["POST"])
def update():
    assert request.method == "POST"
    signature = request.headers.get("X-Hub-Signature")
    if not signature or not signature.startswith("sha1="):
        abort(400, "X-Hub-Signature required")

    sha_name, sinature = signature.split("=")
    if sha_name != "sha1":
        abort(501)

    # Create local hash of payload
    digest = hmac.new(github_secret.encode(), msg=request.data, digestmod="sha1").hexdigest()


    # Verify signature
    if not hmac.compare_digest(signature, digest):
        abort(400, "Invalid signature")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was for all future googlers, I used `request.data` which was None because the content-type header was "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" thx to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23898949/11132447) for explaining that so I had to use `request.get_data()` instead