# Make AJAX post to flask endpoint with a form and other data

Tags: ajax, flask

I am trying to send two pieces of data - a form and an array via AJAX to a Flask endpoint. My javascript with only sending the form is here:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_button', function(){
    let form_data = $('#form').serialize();
    let other_data = updateOtherData();

    req  = $.ajax({
        url : url_final,
        type : 'POST',
        data : form_data
    });
    req.done(function(data){
    //does some updates to page here
    });
});
```

And in my flask endpoint this works just fine with doing something like:

```
@app.route('/process_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_form():
  form = MyForm()
  if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
  #do something here
  return some_data_back
```

However, I would like to send `other_data` along with `form_data`.  So I have tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_button', function(){
    let form_data = $('#form').serialize();
    let other_data = updateOtherData();

    req  = $.ajax({
        url : url_final,
        type : 'POST',
        data : {'form': form_data, 'other': JSON.stringify(other_data)}
    });
    req.done(function(data){
    //does some updates to page here
    });
});
```

And updated my endpoint to something like:

```
@app.route('/process_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_form():
  form = MyForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = #Turn this back to a FlaskForm object
      other_data = #Just get this as a string
  if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
      #do something here
  return some_data_back
```

I have tried a lot of different parts in the above where I cant get it to work. I have tried request.form, request.data, and request.get_json (in which I set contentType in ajax call).

I have looked at many similar questions such as:
[Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)
and
[Get raw POST body in Python Flask regardless of Content-Type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999990/get-raw-post-body-in-python-flask-regardless-of-content-type-header) which looked very promising, but everything kept coming across empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 'request.json'

```
@app.route('/process_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_form():
form = MyForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
  content = request.json 
  form = content['form']
  other_data = content['other']
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
  #do something here
return some_data_back
```