# how to send data from android device to python website

Tags: android, python, web

I want to create a website by using python.I created an android app it send values to a particular website, i want to read the values in website and have to display it on website by using python.I have the android side code for sending the data.I need code for receiving the data in website by using python script.

Comment: I implemented some thing like that before i am using web services which connect between  your web and the android client side , android will connect to web services and save the data and show it for website

Comment: i have a website only. Nothing in it. How to add these kinda webservices thing to ma website .. i need some python coding.??

Comment: Can you suggest me some example's or anything .. so that i can look into it.!!

Comment: @AlvinVarghese You might want to try Flask.  See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go is to use 'Flask.'

There's a brief SO question/answer regarding basic functionality [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-whole-request-post-body-in-python-flask)  It includes the necessary code (~6 lines, I believe,) but I'll replicate it here for your convenience:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_request():
    data = request.data
    # use data here
```

The product's quick start guide is located [here.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I will look into that and will tell you. Thank You.!!

Comment: Being new to Python, you may need to research 'pip' so you can do a 'pip install flask'.  Also, you may need to 'easy_install pip' before that.  On a OS X, you must do both of those things before you can easily use most 3rd party libraries.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

look i am not python developer but i think it same structure you will use in all language  , you need to make web services in python

http://www.diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/index.html?utm_content=buffer38256&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=google&utm_campaign=Buffer

this kind with services deal with xml data to transfer data from android client to your server , and when you finish your services you will using KSOP2 Lib in android to deal with this services

http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html

this way i implemented before and help me

Comment: I will look into that and will tell you. Thank You.!!