# Getting value from select tag using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new to Flask and I'm having trouble getting the value from my select tag. I have tried `request.form['comp_select']` which returns a Bad Request. However, when I try using `request.form.get('comp_select')`, my return page returns a blank list "[]".

My html:

```html
<form class="form-inline" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Please select</span>
            <select name="comp_select" class="selectpicker form-control">
              {% for o in data %}
              <option value="{{ o.name }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}                                              
            </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My app.py:

```
@app.route("/test" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    select = request.form.get('comp_select')
    return(str(select)) # just to see what select is
```

Sorry in advance if my formatting is off for the post (also new to Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's hard to know for certain from what you've provided, but I believe you need to add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` element.

From the [flask doc for the `request` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object):

> To access form data (data transmitted in a POST or PUT request) you can use the form attribute. ... To access parameters submitted in the URL (?key=value) you can use the args attribute.

So, if you submit your forms via POST, use `request.form.get()`. If you submit your forms via GET, use `request.args.get()`.

This app behaves the way you want it to:

flask_app.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, \
     request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        data=[{'name':'red'}, {'name':'green'}, {'name':'blue'}])

@app.route("/test" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    select = request.form.get('comp_select')
    return(str(select)) # just to see what select is

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

templates/index.html

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Please select</span>
            <select name="comp_select" class="selectpicker form-control">
              {% for o in data %}
              <option value="{{ o.name }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I had the problem do get all values for `select multiple`; `get` will only return the first one. The answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/1534017); one can use `request.getlist`.

Comment: Been looking for someone to explain this so that I could understand it properly. This answer delivers.

Comment: In my case with Bootstrap 5 `form-select` I was only missing the `name` tag. When I added that I got the selected form id in `request.form`