# view multipart form request parameter values using flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm uploading a file to my flask backend and I can't figure out how to access the parameter values in the multipart form.

I can access the uploaded file easily by doing `file = request.files['file']` but can't figure out a way to get the parameter values.

I've tried the following but haven't had any luck:

```
    print(request.data['share'])
    print(request.data['title'])
    print(request.get('share'))
    print(request.get('title'))
```

Comment: What parameter values are you expecting? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: You can refer http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/fileuploads/  ...For example, to get the name of file uploaded, you can try 'file.filename'....

Comment: @Gator_Python by parameters i mean the (key,value) parameters that are used to construct the multipart form.  I'm essentially trying to send data along with the file to my flask app.  I want to access that data.

Comment: @kundan `file.filename` works, but i'm trying to pass additional data with the file.

Comment: How are you passing the arguments ? This will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25268170/1840877

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most form inputs can be retrieved as follows:

```
request.form.get("fieldname")
```

Files can be accessed via

```
request.files.get("fieldname")
```

Where the fieldnames are the `name` attribute in the HTML.

Keep in mind that, just because there's a result for `request.files.get("someName")` doesn't mean a file was actually uploaded. You should check that the filename exists, too, in order to validate if a file was indeed uploaded.

Take for example, the following HTML

```
<form action="/form_endpoint" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="data">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You would access the value the user input in the `data` field by `data = request.form.get("data")`