# Flask form post call - request.form is an empty dict

Tags: flask

Form `login.html`:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" required>
    <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

`app.py`:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.form)    # prints empty dict
    return render_template("login.html")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` parameter of inputs in the form is needed in any html form for it to be `POST`ed, otherwise they are left unprocessed.

So the right html would be `login.html`:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required>
    <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Now flask should be able to `dict` up the input elements by name and value.

Answer (score 0):

It returns empty dict because you don't specify the name of the object you requested.You should specify name from the html :

`<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" required>`

and in Python use something like :

`request.form['username']`
or
`request.form.get('username')`

instead of : `(request.form)`

Also a topic to have a look at : 
[How to get data received in Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request)