# Get nested array sent from frontend in Flask request.form

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Unable to access `cols_data` javascript array in flask request.form.

I have tried following

- `request.form.getlist('cols_data')`- didn't work
- `request.form.getlist('cols_data[]')`- Also didn't work

Find request form data below:

```
_csrf_token:1497597543.06##084136a9d79f2879bd33eaadf1095f41e9323192
cols_data[0][col][a]:2
cols_data[0][col][b]:BELL
cols_data[0][col][c]:0
cols_data[0][col][d]:All
cols_data[0][col][w]:abc,drf,cbf,dfdf
cols_data[0][col][cust_display_name]:2
cols_data[1][col][a]:2
cols_data[1][col][b]:BELL
cols_data[1][col][c]:0
cols_data[1][col][d]:All
cols_data[1][col][w]:as,ds,fd,ef
cols_data[1][col][cust_display_name]:3
cols_data[2][col][a]:2
cols_data[2][col][b]:BELL
cols_data[2][col][c]:0
cols_data[2][col][d]:All
cols_data[2][col][w]:nhh,scni,cjik
cols_data[2][col][cust_display_name]:4
cols_data[3][col][a]:1
cols_data[3][col][b]:MNN
```

Comment: Are you sending the array `cols_data` using html form?

Comment: i saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request. If your array is JSON use request.get_json()

Comment: @Nurzhan cols_data is an array send by jquery ajax

Comment: maybe try to output the "request.get_data()" and see the internal format of your request, it should be JSON

Answer (score -1):

As it has already been said if the data is sent through jquery you need to use:

```
cols_data = request.get_json()  
# Do what you need with cols_data
```

If that does not help try to print `request.args`, `request.form` and `request.data` to see what is in there:

```
print('REQUEST.FORM: ', request.form)
print('REQUEST.ARGS: ', request.args)
print('REQUEST.DATA: ', request.data)
```