# How do I pass an array of objects using AJAX to Flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

```
@app.route('/saveData',  methods=['POST'])
def saveData():
  print(request.data)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 annotations = []

 anno.addHandler('onAnnotationCreated', function(annotation){
  annotations.push(annotation);
 });

 var doneButton = $('#done');
 doneButton.click(function(){  
  $.ajax({
         url: '/saveData',
         data: {annotations:annotations},
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(response) {
             console.log(response);
         },
         error: function(error) {
             console.log(error);
         }
     });
 });
});
```

I have an array of annotation objects in javascript. When I click the done button, I want to pass that array of objects to pass to the Flask function where I can store them in some database. How do I pass the array? When I click the done button currently, I get a console error `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`

The traceback is as follows:

    `KeyError: 0
    127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2017 16:36:21] "POST /saveData HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    [2017-07-17 16:36:23,376] ERROR in app: Exception on /saveData [POST]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/Desktop/annotate/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/home/user/Desktop/annotate/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/home/user/Desktop/annotate/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/home/user/Desktop/annotate/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/home/user/Desktop/annotate/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/home/user/Desktop/annotate/app.py", line 19, in saveData
        return(changed[0])`

Comment: what's not working? what's the error?

Comment: @aws_apprentice when I try to `print(request.form())` it returns a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with flask but, the ajax call looks right. Based on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request) you may need to be using `request.form` instead of `request.data`

Comment: I tried `request.form` and I get a 500 internal server error!

Comment: I also just noticed in the comments this function `request.get_json()`. Does that work any better? Also did you do the necessary imports `from flask import request`?

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work :( What I'm confused about is that in the route in python, how do I refer to the data being passed. Do I just refer to it as `data` so that if I'm trying to print the first object I would just do `request.form(data[0])`

Comment: Also did you do the necessary imports `from flask import request`? It's a dictionary though, so you would reference it by whatever index you set, in your case all of the data would be under the index 'annotations' as set in your ajax method so `data['annotations']`

Comment: the data is passed as an `ImmutableMultiDict` you can go `request.form.to_dict()` to transform it into a dict and extract the elements as such.

Comment: Expanding what @aws_apprentice just mentioned, something like: 
`data = request.form.to_dict()`
`data['annotations'] //actual data you sent in post`

Comment: @aws_apprentice I did `data = request.form.to_dict() \ print(data[0])` but I still keep getting `POST 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` on the console

Comment: it can be many things, first is your debug mode on? second try `return` instead of print.

Comment: @aws_apprentice updated my traceback error at the top

Comment: `KeyError: 0` should give you a clue, look at the data first before you try and index it