# How to POST a line of text to flask REST API?

Tags: python, rest, curl, flask

I'm trying to push an entire line of text like - `Hi, What's up?` to a Flask REST API through curl via - `curl -X POST "http://localhost:5000/predict/Hi, whats up"`.

The issue I have with is when the string being passed is with spaces (special characters) i.e  `curl -X POST "http://localhost:5000/data/Hiwhatsup"` works fine but the earlier one throws a bad request. Can anyone explain why this happens? Or how to circumvent it?

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
@app.route("/data/<string:query>", methods=["POST"])
def data(query):
    incoming = query
    print(incoming)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to POST that? A POST without a request body (as set with -d or similar) is highly unusual...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `'Hi, whats up'` is not a valid string to be used in URLs, you should `urlencode` it before usage to escape symbols and get `'Hi%2C%20whats%20up'`. Since now, you can make a request and handle it

P.S. your view is `/data/<string:query>` but should be `/predict/<string:query>`?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* force this by URL-encoding your query with [`--data-urlencode`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode), combined with [`-G`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G) to force appending of this encoded data as a query argument, and explicitly specifying the `POST` method:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:5000/data' --data-urlencode 'Hi, whats up' -G
```

But you *probably don't actually want* to do it like that. You probably just want to `POST` regularly to your controlled endpoint and use something like:

```
curl 'http://localhost:5000/data' -d 'query=Hi, whats up'
```

In this case, your code has to be modified a little bit to [use `request.form`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/404556):

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["POST"])
def data():
    incoming = request.form.get('query')
    print(incoming)
```