# python request.args empty with ajax post

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-3.x

I am trying to pass data via ajax POST to current py api but always get `ImmytableMultiDict<[]>` when try to print passed values.

Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/users/new', methods=['POST'])
@handle_exceptions_in_web_views
def intromeeting():
   print(request.args)
   firstname, lastname = parse_user_request_args(request.args)

def parse_user_request_args(args):

   firstname = args.get('firstName') or ''

   lastname = args.get('lastName') or ''

   return firstname, lastname
```

js code:

```
$.post('users/new', {

    firstName: 'test first name',
    lastName: 'test last name'

}).done(function(res){

    console.log(res)

}).fail(function (err){

    console.log(err)

});
```

I also tried to use `$.ajax` but got the same result. Should I move data to form or smth ?

Comment: You should be using request.form instead of request.args . request.args is for url parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/8370670

Comment: If you are sending it as JSON you could retrieve data from `.body`