# Inserting data into an Oracle database from a form in Python Flask

Tags: python, oracle, forms, flask, oracle11g

I have a Python code.

```
import cx_Oracle
import re
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'd369342136ecd032f8b4a930b6bb2e0e'

@app.route('/add')
def edited():
    connect = cx_Oracle.connect("********", "********", "******/XE")
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cod_ed = request.form['cod_ed']
    nome_ed = request.form['nome_ed']
    endereco = request.form['endereco']
    telefone = request.form['telefone']
    cidade = request.form['cidade']
    execute = """INSERT INTO editor VALUES
            (:cod_ed, :nome_ed, :endereco, :telefone, :cidade)"""
    cursor.execute(execute, {'cod_ed':cod_ed, 'nome_ed':nome_ed, 'endereco':endereco, 'telefone':telefone, 'cidade':cidade})
    connect.commit()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_data():
    return render_template('forms.html')


@app.route('/post_data', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post_data():
    return redirect(url_for('edited'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = 'localhost', port = 8000, debug=True)
```

And its html correspondante:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    <title>Base de dados</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form methods="POST" action="/post_data">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="element-1" >Codigo:</label>
                <input id="cod_ed" name="cod_ed" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Codigo"/>

                <label for="element-2" >Nome:</label>
                <input id="nome_ed" name="nome_ed" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome"/>

                <label for="element-3" >Endereço:</label>
                <input id="endereco" name="endereco" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Endereço"/>

                <label for="element-4" >Telefone:</label>
                <input  id="telefone" name="telefone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone"/>

                <label for="element-5" >Cidade:</label>
                <input  id="cidade" name="cidade" type="text" class="form control" placeholder="Cidade"/>

                <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Enter">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm relatively new to Flask and Python in general. When I run the forms, they get displayed, but when I try to insert them into the database, I get this:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'cod_ed'
```

What exactly is causing it and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When posting to `/post_data` endpoint the browser recieves a redirection code, and then *gets* `/add` without posting any data, provoking a key error.

You are fetching form elements at the wrong place. You should do the database insertion logic inside `/post_data` and redirect to `/add` afterwards.

Comment: It still is the right thing to do. I'm surprised you still get a key error. Perhaps it is failing for an other reason ? Did you restart the app ? You should also try to do things step by step by making your post correct before inserting to a database (it would also make your question simpler and get more responses). Check for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request

Answer (score 0):

Here you are posting the form data to `/post_data` and redirect it to `/add` so the edited function will not be able to access the request object containing the form data. So just change the form action to `/add` to make it work correctly.

Comment: To make it working first you have to change the methods as method in `forms.html`. Then you have to add methods = ['POST']  to the `/add` route