# request.get_data() vs request.get_json()

Tags: json, ajax, flask

I am using Flask now. I was trying to get data sent from jquery ajax. I have read the tutorial but still mix up the use of this two function(I am just getting started with ajax). I would like to know what kind of data they process and return.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, get_json() function parses the data into a JSON object.

get_data() parses into a bytestring.