# Unable to pass parameters to POST call while testing a Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-unittest

I have a Flask web app written and writing testcases for the same using unittest. Below is how it handles the `signup` route

server.py

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if current_user.__dict__.get('id', None):
        return render_template('login.html')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signup.html')

    else:
        data = request.get_json()
        username = data.get('username', '').lower()
        password = data.get('password', '')
        client = data.get('client', '')['name']
        confirm_password = data.get('confirm_password', '')
```

Inside the test file, there are helper methods to signup

test_unittesting.py

```
def signup(self, username, password, confirm, client):
    return self.app.post(
        '/signup',
        data=json.dumps(dict(username=username, password=password, confirm=confirm, client=client)),
        follow_redirects=True
    )
```

But it does not seem to be working. `request.get_json()` returns empty. The parameters are present in `request.get_data()` and not in `request.get_json()`. I am unable to change the helper method to support the method defined for the route. What must I change in the test file to get it working as `request.get_json()`?

Answer (score 1):

The docs describe the attributes available on the request. In most common cases request.data will be empty because it's used as a fallback:

```
request.data Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a mimetype Flask does not handle.

request.args: the key/value pairs in the URL query string
request.form: the key/value pairs in the body, from a HTML post form, or JavaScript request that isn't JSON encoded
request.files: the files in the body, which Flask keeps separate from form. HTML forms must use enctype=multipart/form-data or files will not be uploaded.
request.values: combined args and form, preferring args if keys overlap
```

All of these are MultiDict instances. You can access values using:

```
request.form['name']: use indexing if you know the key exists
request.form.get('name'): use get if the key might not exist
request.form.getlist('name'): use getlist if the key is sent multiple times and you want a list of values. get only returns the first value.
```

Comment: Its working when accessed via the browser. I want to make it work as a test.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request/16664376#16664376

Comment: The link was a bit helpful. I realize I need to configure the mimetype in the unittest as "application/json". But not able to figure out how to do so.

Comment: You can also set the content type explicitly with something like request.contentType = 'application/json' or request.contentType = JSON_CONTENT_TYPE

Answer (score 0):

The mimetype must be set to `mimetype='application/json'` as an additional parameter inside the post call.

```
def signup(self, username, password, confirm, client):
    return self.app.post(
        '/signup',
        data=json.dumps(dict(username=username, password=password, confirm=confirm, client=client)),
        follow_redirects=True, mimetype='application/json'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def signup(self, username, password, confirm, client):
    return self.app.post(
        '/signup',
        data=json.dumps(dict(username=username, password=password, confirm=confirm, client=client)), content_type='application/json')
```