# How to fetch date from html form into flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to fetch date from html form into flask web application.

```
<input type="date" name="startdate">(html)

startdate = datetime.date(request.form['startdate'])(python-flask)
```

I am getting an error

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 431, in **getitem**
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'startdate'

Comment: Which method did you use in form?

Comment: <input type="date" name="startdate">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data received in Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request)

Comment: `request.values`

Comment: start_date = request.values['startdate']
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 1415, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'startdate'  Again it is throwing the same error

Comment: provide full form

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch date from input field (type=date), You will always receive date in string format (yyyy-mm-dd), and you can parse this directly as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                     request.form['startdate'],
                     '%Y-%m-%d')
```