# Combine multiple WTforms output into one JS variable and get it in flask python

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to figure out how to obtain the values of multiple forms, forge them together and get them into python by using flask requests. 
I would like to have only one submit button. When it is pressed all the chosen options in all the forms would be captured on the flusk's side at once.

**Expected result**:

In python I should be able to assign to a variable the users choice in each form, together with the user entry name. I expect to capture with flask the output such as the console log message in the JS function. 
So if the user enters the his/her name, makes a chose in form 1 and form 2, the python variable `o` should be a list for example `['Mary','1','5']`. In addition, it would be better to get a dictionary capturing the name of the forms as well, for example `{'name':'Mary', 'form_1':'1','form_2':'6'}` would be great.

I use a javascript function to get all the chosen options into one variable `score` and printing it out to the console.log.  This is what I would like to forward and capture in flask.

Here is my flask file

```python
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import time


app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_url_path='/static'



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
        return render_template('index_2a.html')


@app.route('/response', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def response():
        w = request.form['say']
        return render_template('index_2a.html', say=request.form['say'])

@app.route('/page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page():
        # THIS IS WHAT I DON'T KWNO ???
        o = request.form.getlist('options')
        o1= request.form.getlist('submit_it')
        o2= request.form.getlist('design')
        o3 = request.form.getlist('options2')
        o4 = request.form.getlist('footer')
        print(o,o1,o2,o3,o4)
        return render_template('index_2a.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8899)
```

and the corresponding `index_2a.html` template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

    <style type="text/css">

.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font-size: 11px;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="footer">

     <form action="{{ url_for('response') }}" method="post">
   <label for="say"> Enter your name:</label><br>
   <input id="say" name="say" ><br>
  </form> 


 <form id="brand" action="{{ url_for('page') }}" method="post" >
  <p>
  <input class="q1" type="radio" name="options" id="option1" value='1'> Option1 
  <input class="q1" type="radio" name="options" id="option2" value='2'> Option2 
  <input class="q1" type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value='3'> Option3 

  </p>

 </form>

 <form id="design" action="{{ url_for('page') }}" method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">
  <p>
  <input  class="q2" type="radio" name="options" id="option4" value='4'> Option4
  <input  class="q2" type="radio" name="options" id="option5" value='5'> Option5
  <input  class="q2" type="radio" name="options" id="option6" value='6'> Option6
  </p>

  <p><button name='submit_it' onclick="check()" method="post">Submit my scores!</button> </p>
 </form>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var score=[];
function check () {
 var users = document.getElementsByName("say");
    var methods = document.getElementsByName("options");
 score.push( users[0].value );
    for (var i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
         if (methods[i].checked == true) {
             score.push(methods[i].value);
            }
    }
 console.log(score.toString())
 return score.toString()
}

function submitForm() {
  return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?\n'+ score.toString());
}



    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: to get the payload as JSON you could use request.get_json(), alternatives are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. if you can write this into an answer in the context of the question, that would be great.