# TypeError TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable , post request

Tags: python, post, http-post

I am trying to call my own `Post API` from python function ,  there is no issue in api side , it's working fine , but when i am trying to call `POST` `API from Python function`

below is my code

```
@app.route('/dhiru_post', methods=['GET'])
def dhiru_post():
    url = "https://www.mydomainamehere.com/api_new/"

    payload = {"number": 12524,
               "api_type": "news_listing",
               "slug": "life-mantra",
               "start": 0,
               "end": 10}
    response_decoded_json = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    response_json = response_decoded_json.json()
    return response_json
```

> Note: https://www.mydomainamehere.com/api_new/ this is not the exact
>   url, please ignore .

**Error** :
open this url :
https://dhiru-ai-quantomsoftech.herokuapp.com/webhook_dhiru

```
TypeError
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 269, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1119, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

Comment: The problem is that `return response_json`. The request is successful, so you should ensure the type of `response_json` is supported.

Comment: @Sraw i am beginner in python , i am not sure how i'll fix this , can you please post some sample for post request , which has JSON input and  JSON output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your handler as follow:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/dhiru_post', methods=['GET'])
def dhiru_post():
    url = "https://www.mydomainamehere.com/api_new/"
    payload = {
        "number": 12524,
        "api_type": "news_listing",
        "slug": "life-mantra",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 10
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    return jsonify(response.json())
```

So basically you need to return a response instead of a dict, `jsonify` will do that for you: set the correct content-type and convert the `response.json()` dict to string and use that as content.

Comment: You need to import it `from flask import jsonify`

Comment: Ok and also , in post request the paramters in not sent to server , do i need to convert that as well using jsonify ??

Comment: Hi , you answer is working i'll accept ,can you please help me to send paramters to server , now there is no exception but still i am not able to send parameter in your example

Comment: Hi again, notice that you are sending a POST request, so the data is included in the body of the request and not as query parameters. For more info please read this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/4586108

Comment: In Starlette you can use `return JSONResponse(response)`.