# Sending image via HTTP form-data to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, xmlhttprequest, postman

I'm using Postman to help me generate an HttpRequest. I want to send an image blob (POST request) to my Flask server to be processed with OpenCV.

When I manually select the file to send as binary data (i.e. in Postman: Body -> binary -> choose files), I can then access the blob in Flask via `request.data`. However, when I try to send as form-data, I'm not sure how to access the blob and I get bad requests or other errors.

I'm sending the request as: (in Postman) Body -> form-data -> Key: "image", Value: . In Flask I'm trying to access the image via `request.form['image']`, according to what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request)., but this returns status 400 bad request.

[Screenshot of Postman](https://ibb.co/ct7Gn9H)

Python code snippet:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/croprect", methods = ["POST"])
def crop_rect():
    r = request
    blob = r.form['image']
        nparr = np.fromstring(blob, np.uint16)
        img = cv.imdecode(nparr, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Edit: I have already checked the answers [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request). I've tried `request.form.get("image")`, `request.args.get("image", "")`, but none of these are working and I'm definitely misunderstanding which method to use.

Comment: please see added clarification. I don't believe this is duplicate.

Comment: try this: image = request.files['image'].read()

Comment: Anytime, glad it helped.