# Data not coming through when using POST request

Tags: python, flask

I've got this boilerplate code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.get_json()
        return jsonify({'you sent:': text}), 201
    else:
        return jsonify({'about': 'hakuna matata'})

@app.route('/multi/<int:num>', methods=['GET'])
def get_multiply10(num):
    return jsonify({'result': num*10})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when I jump into Python interpreter I can interact with the API with GET like this:

```
from requests import get, post

get('http://localhost:5000').json()
```

and it returns expected output, but when I try to execute POST request:

```
post('http://localhost:5000', data={'data': 'bombastic !'}).json()
```

I get returned `None` from the `text` variable, meaning POST request is being acknowledged but the data isn't making it through to the variable.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you get 201 in both cases? The POST should return 201 while the GET should return 200.

Comment: I'm getting 201 on POST and 200 on GET which is fine.

Comment: OK. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request about the options you have to look for the data you post. I thin it is under `form`

Comment: Try `json` parameter instead: `requests.post('http://localhost:5000', json={'data': 'bombastic !'})`

Comment: @m01010011  That worked ! So when working with json (dictionary) data I need to use the `json` parameter and not `data` parameter. Feel free to post it as a solution and I'll tick it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from your case, many websites require JSON-encoded data. So, you'll have to encode it before posting:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `json` parameter...

```
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

... and let `requests` encode it for you.

Comment: [Docs link](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)