# Flask: Get gzip filename sent from Postman

Tags: python-3.x, flask, postman

I am sending a gzip file from Postman to a Flask endpoint. I can take that binary file with `request.data` and read it, save it, upload it, etc.

My problem is that I can't take its name. How can I do that?

My gzip file is called "test_file.json.gz" and my file is called "test_file.json".

How can I take any of those names?

Edit:

I'm taking the stream data with io.BytesIO(), but this library doesn't contain a name attribute or something, although I can see the file name into the string if I just:

```
>>>print(request.data)
>>>b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xca\xb1\xd3]\x00\x03test_file.json\x00\xab\xe6RPP\xcaN\xad4T\xb2RP*K\xcc)M5T\xe2\xaa\x05\x00\xc2\x8b\xb6;\x16\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Please post the code which handles the upload.

Comment: It's nothing to be posted. I need a simplistic way to get that file's name. It's clear that taking the stream with BytesIO doesn't give me the file name as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comment, I think the code which handles your upload is relevant here.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/2052575) regarding `request.data`:

> `request.data` Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a mimetype Flask does not handle.

The [recommended way](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/#a-gentle-introduction) to handle file uploads in flask is to use:

```
file = request.files['file']
```

- `file` is then of type: [`werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage).
- `file.stream` is the stream, which can be read with `file.stream.read()` or simply `file.read()`
- `file.filename` is the filename as specified on the client.
- `file.save(path)` a method which saves the file to disk.  `path` should be a string like `'/some/location/file.ext'`

[source](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/d129d17066768238139b8f8a5d667d9a4f4d68db/docs/datastructures.rst#others)