# Encoding Methods For Sending Images to ML service

Tags: python, web-services, machine-learning, flask

I have an image ML service running behind Flask. From most of what I've seen online, one first encodes an image in base64 on the client, and then sends the payload to the service, which decodes the image and proceeds to do its predictions. As an example:

**Client-Side**

```
with open("my_image.jpeg", 'rb') as f:
    image_b64 = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8')

request.post("https://my-service", json = {'image_b64' : image_b64})
```

**Server-Side**

```
image_b64 =  request_json.get('image_b64')
image = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(image_b64))
...
```

This approach seems to suffer from a number of serious overhead issues which crop up when the model server is receiving many requests simultaneously:

1. base64 encodings tend to inflate file size by 30%.
2. The encoding/decoding process is *slow* for both client and service, which bottlenecks the rate at which the model can actually do predictions. If it's relevant here, I'm primarily interested in CPU-only serving, so no GPU involved.

What I'm wondering about is: **is there a better way?**. I'm guessing there are probably some smart ways of threading the decoding/encoding process, but it still seems woefully inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

[POST Multiple Multipart-Encoded Files](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files) aka provide `files` argument to the `request.post` method call...

## Client

```
with open("my_image.jpeg", 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': f}
    request.post("https://my-service", files = files)
```

## Server

```
@app.route('/some_route')
def some_route():
    data = request.files['file']
```

`data` is now a `werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage` object, which you can do [several things with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58934639/2052575).

You'll most likely want to get the bytes with `data.read()` and pass that on to your ML functions.

Comment: Thanks! What I’m curious about though is why this method is not used more widely? For example AWS Rekognition, GCS and other ML services mostly seem to use the base64 approach.

Comment: @AlexR. I have no idea.  Whatever works for you I guess :D