# Cannot open Image file got from request.files.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, request, face-recognition

I am trying to make a face recognition API with Flask and deepface library.
But I am not able to open the image it's giving me different errors. Please give me a solution.

**Code:**

```
@app.route('/detect', methods=['POST'])
def recognize():
    image_path = request.files.get('image')
    try:
        analysis = DeepFace.analyze(image_path)
        return jsonify(analysis)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})
```

**error**

```
  "error": "object of type 'FileStorage' has no len()"
```

Tried to open the image

```
    with open(image_path, 'r') as image:
            analysis = DeepFace.analyze(image)
            return jsonify(analysis)
```

I get the error

```
{"errors": "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `image_path` holds object of type `FileStorage` which knows location of a file and does not hold actual image data. First you need to load that image file and then try to analyze it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to lead the image?

```

Comment: You can read about it here [link](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileStorage.html).

Answer (score 0):

A werkzeug `FileStorage` object has several methods as I've [documented in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58934639/2052575).

Sounds like you need to save the image to a temporary location first, then do the analysis.

I would create a directory called `uploads` on your server, then set this in the app config:

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads'
```

Then in your route, use the `uuid.uuid4` function to create a temporary filename.  Something like:

```
from uuid import uuid4

@app.route('/detect', methods=['POST'])
def recognize():

    tmp_fname = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], uuid4().__str__())

    image = request.files['image']
    image.save(tmp_fname)
    try:
        analysis = DeepFace.analyze(tmp_fname)
        return jsonify(analysis)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})
```

This leaves the saved images on the filesystem, so you may wish to do some cleanup on this directory, or do something like `os.remove('tmp_fname')` after running the analysis.

I'm not sure whether `Deepface.analyze` accepts a stream as its first argument.  The [README](https://github.com/serengil/deepface) suggests it only accepts a filename as a string.  You could try doing `Deepface.analyze(image.stream)` to avoid having to deal with saving the temporary file (keep everything in memory instead), but this may not be supported.