# How to open and process .rtf files in Flask

Tags: python, flask, rtf

I am trying to send a request including a rtf file and process it in Flask.

In my python script, I used the striprtf lib to read this file and then process it.

```
rtf = Path(file_path).read_text()
text = rtf_to_text(rtf)
```

Now I want to wrap this script into flask. I got error said: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. How can I read this rtf file in the flask?

```
file = request.files['file']

text = rtf_to_text(file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `read` method of `file`, which is a [`werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58934639/2052575).

You'll then need to decode this to provide `rtf_to_text` with the string it expects.

```
file = request.files['file']
as_string = file.read().decode('utf-8')
text = rtf_to_text(as_string)
```

Comment: @v25still get error: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object