# Flask: How do I pass an uploaded file as input to a method? AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, flask

I'm completely new to flask (in fact I've just started this morning) and so far I've only managed to implement a basic upload function (taken from the flask doc). The file upload works but I just can't seem to figure out how to pass the file into another method (mining). When I do, I always get the error message: **AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'lower'**. It would mean the world to me to receive any kind of help! Thank you all in advance.

```
def mining(xes):
    log = xes_importer.apply(xes)
    tracefilter_log_pos = attributes_filter.apply_events(log, ["complete"], parameters={attributes_filter.Parameters.ATTRIBUTE_KEY: "lifecycle:transition", attributes_filter.Parameters.POSITIVE: True})
    variants = pm4py.get_variants_as_tuples(tracefilter_log_pos)
    Alpha(variants.keys())
    Heuristic(variants.keys(), 1, 0.5)


UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/Users/jenny/processmining_lab/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['xes'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
        # empty file without a filename.
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return mining(file)
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

[Here is the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Njv6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you're `mining` function looks like.

`file` is a [`werkzeug.FileStorage` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58934639/2052575) which has it's own various methods.

So (without seeing) your `mining` function it should probably be something like:

```
def mining(file_obj):

    lower_fname = file_obj.filename.lower()
    data = file_obj.read()

    # Do something
```

The `AttributeError` you mention sounds like you're trying to run the `lower` method of something which doesn't return a string.

As a side-note: it's difficult to know *where* in your code this exception hasn't occured as you never posted the full traceback.

---

**EDIT**

> My mining function is actually at the top of the code I've inserted.  I've also now included the traceback.

Looks like you're using [PM4Py](https://pm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de/documentation) for which this document states:

> ```
> from pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes import importer as xes_importer
> log = xes_importer.apply('<path_to_xes_file.xes>')
> ```

So you need to actually pass a **file path** to the mining function.

I suggest changing your main code to do:

```
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            sfilename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            output_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], sfilename)

            # Now save to this `output_path` and pass that same var to your mining function
            file.save(output_path)
            return mining(output_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My mining function is actually at the top of the code I've inserted.

Comment: I've also now included the traceback.

Comment: @icbidt1018 see my edit ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't believe I missed that one, but now it works!