# Code is not going to Next Step in HTML/Flask/Python Application

Tags: python, html, database, postgresql, flask

This is my python code that is the route for a search bar I'm making for a Library database. It always runs the first step, but even after a user submits a search, it does not go to next step. I would like for after the user submits a search, the step will change in the request.form and then it will run the second step. However, in the debugger, it is never showing "getting here". It is evident that the code is never reaching the second step. I'm imagining it has something to do with my request.form not registering the new step.

```
@app.route('/browse',methods=['get','post'])
def Browse():
    debug("form data=" + str(request.form))
    if "step" not in request.form:
        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select booktitle, genre, datepublished, authorfirst, authorlast from book natural join author natural join writes')
        rowlist = cursor.fetchall()
        return render_template("browse.html", step="display_books", entries=rowlist)
    else:
        debug("getting here")
        newdb = get_db()
        newcursor = newdb.cursor()
        #get search from form
        newcursor.execute("select booktitle,genre,datepublished,authorfirst,authorlast from book natural join author natural join writes where booktitle=%s", [request.form['searchentry']])
        newdb.commit()
        newrowlist = newcursor.fetchall()
        return render_template("browse.html", step="search_books", newentries =newrowlist)
```

Here is the html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Browse</title>
    <style>
    body {
                background-image: url(https://storage.cloud.google.com/book_lib_img/Bookworm%20Webpage/wallpaper4.jpg?cloudshell=false&folder&organizationId);
                height: 500px;
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100%100%;
                position: absolute;

            }
        h1 {
             color: white;
             font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
             font-size:150%;
             position: absolute; 
             color:white;
             TOP:200px;
             LEFT:520px
            }


        #Add a black background color to the top navigation 
        ul {
             list-style-type: none;
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px;
             overflow: hidden;
             background-color: #333;
             position: fixed;
             top:150;
             width: 100%;

            }

        li {
            float: left;
            border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }

</style> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1></h1>

    <img src=https://storage.cloud.google.com/book_lib_img/Bookworm%20Webpage/Bookworm.jfif alt="HTML5 Icon" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:5px; LEFT:5px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:100px">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a>
    <li><a href="/browse">Select Preference</a>
    <li><a href="/edit">My Account</a>
    <li><a href="/signup">Create Account</a>
    <li><a href="/login">Login</a>
    <ul>
    {% if step == "display_books" %}
        <h2>Browse entries </h2>
            <form style="color:white;background-color:gray;padding-left: 40px;border="1"">
                <form action="{{ url_for('Browse') }}" method="get">
                <h3>Search by:</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="title" value="Title" checked> Title <br>
                <input type="radio" name="author" value="Author">Author
                <input type="text" style="width:300px" name="searchentry" placeholder="Search for...">
                <input type="radio" name="genre" value="Genre">Genre<br>
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="search_books">
                <input type = "submit">
            </form>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="700">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="700">
                            <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Author</th>
                                <th>Published</th>
                                <th>Genre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="width:700px; height:340px; overflow:auto;">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="700">
                                {% for entry in entries %}
                                    <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
                                        <td>{{entry.booktitle}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.authorfirst+" "+entry.authorlast}}<br>
                                        <td>{{entry.datepublished}}</td>
                                        <td>{{entry.genre}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    {% else %}

        <h2>Your Search Results</h2>
            <form style="color:white;background-color:gray;padding-left: 40px;border="1"">
                <form action="{{ url_for('Browse') }}" method="get">
                <h3>Search by:</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="title" value="Title" checked> Title <br>
                <input type="radio" name="author" value="Author">Author
                <input type="text" style="width:300px" name="searchentry" placeholder="Search for...">
                <button type="button">Search</button><br>
                <input type="radio" name="genre" value="Genre">Genre<br>
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="search_books">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="700">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="700">
                            <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Author</th>
                                <th>Published</th>
                                <th>Genre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="width:700px; height:340px; overflow:auto;">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="700">
                                {% for newentry in newentries %}
                                    <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
                                        <td>{{newentry.booktitle}}</td>
                                        <td>{{newentry.authorfirst+" "+newentry.authorlast}}<br>
                                        <td>{{newentry.datepublished}}</td>
                                        <td>{{newentry.genre}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    {%endif%}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you defining "steps" as the `if` and `else` blocks of the code?

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb Yes, it's never getting to else block in either parts of my code. However, I should note that the URL is changing from /browse to /browse?title=Title&searchentry=hello&step=search_books

Comment: When you print your debug, what do you get? Do you see "step" ever appear in what is displayed when you print `request.form`?

Comment: It always only shows form data=ImmutableMultiDict([])

Comment: Dig deeper. It looks like that dict is empty.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. I'm aware it's empty, but I'm not sure why it is empty, considering I'm getting the user input. it's not going to the request.form and I'm not sure why.

Comment: not too familiar with Flask, but did you try `request.args`?

Comment: For reference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request

Comment: That was it!!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll put a proper answer in for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request), it appears you are trying to get the form data when looking in `request.form`, which contains form data from HTTP POST requests, but really, you are looking for the key-value arguments in the URL.

To get these arguments, instead of using `request.form`, use `request.args`.