# Passing values from HTML/Javascript to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I need to pass values from my JS code to my Flask code. I am creating a JSON in my JS code and I used AJAX to send it via POST method to my Flask :

```
$("#btnSubmitRejetRefModele").click(function() {
    var movies = {
        'title': 'SPY',
        'release_date': '12/02'
    }   

    $.ajax({
        url: '/rejets_modeles',
        type: 'POST',
        datax: JSON.stringify(movies),
        dataType: "json"

    }).done(function(result){
        //console.log(result)
    })
});
```

And my python code `app.py` :

```
@app.route('/rejets_modeles', methods=["POST","GET"])
def rejets_modeles():
   if request.method == 'POST':
    datax = {}
    datax = request.get_json()

    print("--------------")
    print(datax)
```

And the result of this in my Terminal :

> -------------- None

How can I get my datax printed in my python code ? Thank you

Comment: Where the `datax` in `$.ajax(...)` is come from? Replace `datax` to `data`.

Comment: Same problem if i use data in my JS and in my python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS sent it as form data so try print(request.form)

Comment: Yes you're right. I get this : ImmutableMultiDict([('{"title":"SPY","release_date":"12/02"}', '')]), now how can I store just the json into a variable ?

Comment: Solved. I used : 
for key in request.form.to_dict():
            v = json.loads(key)

Answer (score 0):

> ImmutableMultiDict([('{"title":"SPY","release_date":"12/02"}', '')]), now how can I store just the json into a variable ?

When an ajax call comes to flask, itll already be a proper python dict thus no need for any extra stuff, thus should be able to use `title = request.form['title']` for example.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/rejets_modeles',
    type: 'POST',
    datax: movies,
    dataType: "json"

})
```

without stringify, there's no need to make it into a string and it'll work as expected (probably).

[Incoming request data (flask docs)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data), [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)