# Parse GET request body in Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, request, python-requests

An API I'm using can only send GET request bodies (or their documentation is unclear).

I can see the body fine from nginx (via $request_body logging). But the `request.body` object is completely empty in flask every time.

I confirmed it's a GET request in flask in my endpoint. Is there any way to read the `request.body` of a GET request?

Comment: I don't think `request.body` is a property of the `request` object. Try `request.json` or `request.data`? Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)

Comment: Tried all them unfortunately.