# Python Flask - Request object doesn't exist even though it's imported

Tags: python, flask

I have an extremely bare bones python REST application:

### main.py

```
from app import app

def main():

    parser = ArgumentParser(description="Character information hosting server!")
    parser.add_argument('--parse-word-doc', dest="parse_doc", required=False, action='store_true',
                        help='Parses a word document for characters and then serializes them with pickle to a file')
    parser.add_argument('--source-file', dest="source_file", type=str, required=False,
                        help='Path and name of the source word document you want to read from. Defaults to source.docx.',
                        default="source.docx")
    parser.add_argument('--port', dest="port", required=False, type=int, default=5000,
                        help='Specify the port you want Flask to run on')
    parser.add_argument('--log-level', metavar='LOG_LEVEL', dest="log_level", required=False, type=str, default="info",
                        choices=['debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error', 'critical'],
                        help='The log level at which you want to run.')

    args = parser.parse_args()  # type: argparse.Namespace

    if not Path(args.source_file).is_file():
        logging.error("Could not find " + args.source_file + ". Are you sure you got the path right?")
        exit(1)

    logging.info("Reading data from the file \"database\" from disk")
    with open('database', 'rb') as database:
        characters = pickle.load(database)
        app.config['DATABASE'] = characters

    if args.log_level:
        if args.log_level == "debug":
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
            app.config['DEBUG'] = True
        elif args.log_level == "info":
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        elif args.log_level == "warning":
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
        elif args.log_level == "error":
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
        elif args.log_level == "critical":
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=args.port)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### app/init.py

```
from flask import Flask

# Initialize the app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the views
from app import views
```

### app/config.py

```
import os


class Config(object):

    # Enable Flask's debugging features. Should be False in production
    DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG') or True
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'default-secret-just-for-csrf-attacks-nbd'
```

### app/views.py

```
from flask import request
from app import app


@app.route('/api/lookup', methods=['GET'])
def lookup():

    input_text = request.args.get('character_to_lookup')

    if input_text in app.config['DATABASE']:
        return app.config['DATABASE'][input_text]
    else:
        return {}
```

### Problem

If I send a simple curl command: `curl -X GET -d '{"character_to_lookup": "test"}' http://127.0.01:5000/api/lookup -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

and check in PyCharm for debugging - request simply doesn't exist at all. It isn't set to none, it just doesn't exist. There must be something about the app context I'm missing, but it isn't clear.

[image: Problem]

The only thing I've been able to find online is that you need to import request, which I've done and I can't think of another reason that request simply wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that request.args in flask refers specifically to data passed via the url. Flask uses different values in request for different types of data. In my case, I wanted JSON so I had to use `request.get_json()`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request) for a great explanation.