# Why am i getting an error when I am sending JSON data from Javascript to Flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

This is my javascript code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/jstoflask",
            data: {
                1: "Welcome",
                2: "to",
                3: "Geeks",
                4: "for",
                5: "Geeks"
            },

            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success', data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my flask code

```
@app.route('/jstoflask',methods=["POST"])
def jstoflask():
    data=request.form('data')
    print(data)  
    return jsonify(data)
```

I'm getting an error : TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable.
What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: data=request.form('data') i suspect your problem is in this line. You are not sending any form or field with name "data"

Comment: have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request it may help you

Answer (score 0):

It's because `request.form` is not a method you can call. It's the payload as an `ImmutableMultiDict`. You can change the line to `data = request.form` and you'd be able to see the value.

Since the request object is a dictionary, you can access the data by passing a key like so: `request.form['1']`.

[Official Docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#accessing-request-data)

Comment: How do I get the data such that it is not an InmutableMultiDict?

Comment: Added an example to the answer