# Connecting Bootstrap search box with Python based search engine

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4, jinja2, lektor

I am attempting to integrate Elasticsearch as a search engine for my static website. I use the Python package "Lektor" as my static website generator. I have been able to automate indexing all my webpages into Elasticsearch. Additionally, I am using Bootstrap to have a navigation bar on the top of the website. I have added the relevant search bar code from Bootstrap and it looks exactly like I want it to. My issue is with connecting the Bootstrap search bar to my Python code that queries the Elasticsearch cluster I have set up. I am hoping to process the search bar data and send it as an argument to my Python querying function. Is this possible? I know how to do this with Flask and setting up an endpoint, but in this case, I do not know how to set a specific endpoint for search that reacts to the search bar's form data.

Comment: Certainly possbile. `my Python code that queries the Elasticsearch cluster`: Can you show the usage of this, and the sample response?  Also a demonstration of anything you have already tried to put this together will help you get an answer :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding! The Bootstrap component looks like: ```<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>```

Comment: The framework uses Jinja2 templating and so the function is available to be called directly in the HTML, I just do not know how to obtain the form data. I know usually it sends a POST to a specific endpoint that then handles the form data, but I was wondering if there was another way to access the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request