# Handle post request in flask and bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I've been trying to build an API for more than 4 hours now and I searched and asked everywhere I could but I can't find help. The problem is at the level of handling POST requests. I tried with NodeJS (testify and express (as well as middlewares)) and Python (Flask, bottle) and I still can't get why I get an empty object with express or None in python. I have the following code with bottle

```py
 1 from bottle import run, Bottle, post, request, redirect
 2 import json
 3
 4 pika = Bottle()
 5
 6 @post("/shorturl")
 7 def shorten():
 8     data = request.json
 9     #data = json.dumps(rdata)
10     print(data)
11     return f"You posted {data}"
12
13 run(host="localhost", port=3000, debug=True)
```

And I had the following code at the beginning (I deleted and restarted from scratch) - you can find tweet [here](https://twitter.com/JosiasWing/status/1294575038939779073?s=19).

I can't get None with flask and bottle when using `request.get_json()` and `request.json()` respectively which I've found are the way to do it from the docs.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you [edit] to include the Flask code in your question, this has nothing to do with Flask so I'm removing the tag

Comment: Also, you haven't said how you're calling your endpoints

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request
Have you checked this?

The `post`-ed data is generally present as key-value pairs in `request.form` as is mentioned in top answer in the link.

Comment: Thanks. I use an app to call my endpoints Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.tiagohm.restler

Answer (score 2):

Your python code seems to be correct, because I tried and it worked.
For troubleshooting you can insert:

```
print(request.headers['Content-Type']) #output should be: application/json'
print(request.body.read())             #output should be like: b'{"key":"value"}'
```

I used Postman and when I tried the first time, I made the mistake to select body **form** instead of **raw**. In Postman you have to write **Content-Type:appliction/json** in the header manually and insert the json as **raw**.
I assume in Restler it's similar (I never used Restler).

So if you have to configure it manually, make sure that your header contains **'Content-Type':'application/json'**
[image]
And your body is set to **raw** and look like this.
[image]
If for example **form-data** was selected, the manually set header would not be used by postman and **print(request.header['Content-Type'])** would output something like this: **multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------742283902180513961059188**

Could imagine Restler has the same snare.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it after adding the MIME type application/JSON for Content-Type

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to handle a dynamic routing of the api.  Now you just have to add methods to the API class and they are automatically picked up by the bottle app. I am merging POST and GET into one method string to merge query parameters and forms into one payload which you can access via `self.payload`

```
import ujson as json
from login import User

def check(data):
    try:
        if isinstance(data, (str,bytes)):
            return json.loads(data)
    except:
        return data
    return data

def merge_dicts(*args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in args:
        result.update(dictionary or {})
    return result

class API:
    def __init__(self, payload, user):
        self.payload = payload
        self.option = ''
        self.request = None

    @classmethod
    def bot(cls, request, option, user):
        payload = merge_dicts(dict(request.forms), dict(request.query.decode()))  # merge query and form inputs
        slf = cls(payload, user)
        slf.request = request
        slf.option = str(option)
        return slf

    def test(self): # localhost/api/test
        return self.payload

@get('/api/<command>')
@post('/api/<command>')
@get('/api/<command>/<option>')
@post('/api/<command>/<option>')
def routeapi(command='', option=''):
    user = User()
    wapi = API.bot(request, option, user)
    func = getattr(wapi, f"{command}", None)
    if callable(func):
        result = func()
        if result:
            if request.method == 'GET':
                response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
                response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
            return {command:json.check(result)}
        else:
            return {command:None}
```