# Getting Request Body in Google Cloud Function Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup Stripe Webhooks on Google Cloud Functions in Python.  However, I'm running into an issue with getting the request body from the function. Please have a look at my. code below.

Essentially how can I get the `request.body`? Is this provided in Cloud Functions somehow?

```
import json
import os
import stripe
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

stripe.api_key = 'XXXX'

# Using Django
@csrf_exempt
def my_webhook_view(request):
  payload = request.body # This doesn't work!
  event = None
  print(payload)

  try:
    event = stripe.Event.construct_from(
      json.loads(payload), stripe.api_key
    )
  except ValueError as e:
    # Invalid payload
    return HttpResponse(status=400)

  # Handle the event
  if event.type == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
    payment_intent = event.data.object # contains a stripe.PaymentIntent
    # Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
    # handle_payment_intent_succeeded(payment_intent)
    print(payment_intent)
  elif event.type == 'payment_method.attached':
    payment_method = event.data.object # contains a stripe.PaymentMethod
    # Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
    # handle_payment_method_attached(payment_method)
    # ... handle other event types
    print(payment_intent)
  else:
    print('Unhandled event type {}'.format(event.type))

  return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: It looks like the Request object won't contain a full payload *if its contents can NOT be parsed*.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request).  request.body is a nodejs construct, which is not available in python/Flask.

Comment: The answer depends on how you POST or PUT the data and the mimetype. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/8016720

Comment: How do you call your functions? And can you try with `request.get_data()`?

Answer (score 2):

The `request` object is an instance of [`flask.Request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request).

Depending on what you want to do with the request body, you could call `request.args`, `request.form`, `request.files`, `request.values`, `request.json`, or `request.data` in the event that the request body hasn't been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like that way:

```
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    payload_bytes = payload.encode('utf-8')
    
    sig_header = request.headers['Stripe-Signature']

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload_bytes, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        raise e
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        raise e
```