# Issues sending/interpreting JSON sent from Javascript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, json

I am trying to send JSON from Javascript to a Python POST route using Flask. I believe the JSON is sending correctly to Python, except I am struggling to figure out how to access it. In my Python response variable after the POST route occurs, `type(response)` prints `<Response [200]>`. When I print `dir(response)` I get [image]

I see that there is a JSON method within this response, however when I print `response.json()`, I receive the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My Javascript and Python code is below. Appreciate any help.

```js
async function processForm() {
    const luckyNumObj = {num: {fact: "text is here", num: 3}, year: {fact: "text is here", year: 1990}};
    console.log("luckyNumObj:", JSON.stringify(luckyNumObj))
    await axios.post("/api/get-lucky-num", JSON.stringify(luckyNumObj))
};

processForm()
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, session, request, jsonify
import json
import requests
from werkzeug.exceptions import Unauthorized

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "shhhhh"


@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    """Show homepage."""
    return redirect("/api/get-lucky-num")

@app.route("/api/get-lucky-num", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def json_api():
    """JSON API Endpoint"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/api/get-lucky-num')
        data = response.json()

        print("data", data)

        return render_template("index.html")
    
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: wait, is this webserver the one running on port 5000? Because if so, then I think you want to read from `request`(from Flask) to get the posted data, since it currently appears to be GETting itself?

Comment: This part is so over my head and have been trying to grasp the concepts. So, I tried `        print("json", request.json)` after the post request was made and received `None`.

Comment: Is there a better way to communicate between these two languages? I just would like JSON data to be sent from Javascript to that Python route. Could the axios.post url in my Javascript be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up a couple python libraries.

The [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) python library is used for sending out HTTP requests, similar to axios in javascript.
The [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) python library is used for making an HTTP web server.

At the top of your file, you're doing `import requests` which imports the requests library, not the flask library. Later, you're telling the requests library to send a GET request to `http://localhost:5000/api/get-lucky-num`, then you're trying to get the JSON response from the result of that request.

What you were probably trying to do instead was `from flask import request`, which would import flask's request API. From there, you could do `request.json` to get the JSON data that was POSTed to this endpoint. You might have to set the 'Content-Type' header to 'application/json' in javascript when you send the request for flask to interpret it correctly. This can be done as follows:

```
await axios.post("/api/get-lucky-num", JSON.stringify(luckyNumObj), {
  headers: { "content-type": 'application/json' },
})
```

See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request) for more information on getting the POST data from a flask response, and [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for more information on using axios.

Comment: Thank you for this. Starting to have a stronger grasp. Do you know how I could change the Content-Type header to application/json? 

When I print request.get_json() and request.json, I receive 'None'. When I print request.get_json(force=True), I get the correct JSON to print, however my browser shows: Bad Request Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

From your link: "The request must have the application/json content type, or use request.get_json(force=True) to ignore content type". Seems that I might just need to set the 'content-type' header to json?

Comment: I updated the question to show an example of how you might set the Content-Type header with axios - hopefully that helps you.