# Flask - Request.args.get not getting parameters from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a Flask web app that receives AJAX statuses/requests via `request.args.get` however one of my requests aren't being read by my Flask app. The other status `status` works fine, but `doorStatus` does not.

The data is successfully sent by AJAX since I can see the reqeust when I go to dev tools > network in my browser. Am I missing something?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import serial
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

# {{url}}/led?status=on
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def led():
    status = request.args.get('status')
    if status == "on":
        exteriorOn = 'H'
        exteriorOnEncode = exteriorOn.encode()
        ser.write(exteriorOnEncode)
        return jsonify({"message": "Led successfully turned on"})
    elif status == "off":
        exteriorOff = 'C'
        exteriorOffEncode = exteriorOff.encode()
        ser.write(exteriorOffEncode)
        return jsonify({"message": "Led successfully turned off"})
    else:
        return jsonify({"message": "Not a valid status"})


    doorStatus = request.args.get('doorStatus')
    if doorStatus == "open":
        doorOpen = 'L'
        doorOpenEncode = doorOpen.encode()
        ser.write(doorOpenEncode)
        return jsonify({"message": "Door successfully opened"})
    elif doorStatus == "closed":
        doorClosed = 'N'
        doorClosedEncode = doorClosed.encode()
        ser.write(doorClosedEncode)
        return jsonify({"message" : "Door successfulled closed"})
    else:
        return jsonify({"message" : "Not a valid status"})
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#openDoor').on('click', function(e){
    let doorStatus;
    if($(this).text() == 'OPEN') {
    $(this).text('CLOSE')
    doorStatus = 'open';
   } else {

    $(this).text('OPEN');
    doorStatus = 'closed';
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/led',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {doorStatus},
        success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
     }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#exteriorBtn').on('click', function(e){
    let status;
    if($(this).text() == 'Exterior') {
        $(this).text('Turn Off')
        status = 'on';
    } else {
        $(this).text('Exterior');
        status = 'off';
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/led',
        method: 'GET',
        data:{status},
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
     }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your `data` is not formatted correctly.

Comment: It's `data: {status},` right? The exact same works for my `status` ajax call, but not door status. Do you mean it's not consistent with the request in `request.args.get`?

Answer (score 0):

When you GET or POST data, it needs to have a name and value pair.

GET Example:

```
http://www.nowhere.place/webpage.html?status=open
```

You can see the name `status` and it's value `open`.

See more: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> **data**

> Type: PlainObject or String or Array

> Data to be sent to the server. If the HTTP method is one that cannot have an entity body, such as GET, the data is appended to the URL

Plain Object Example:

```
data: { status: "OPEN" }
```

String Example:

```
data: encodeURIComponent("status=OPEN")
```

Array Example:

```
data: [ "OPEN" ]
```

So for your code, I would advise:

```
$('#openDoor').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var door = { status: "" };
  if($(this).text() == 'OPEN') {
    $(this).text('CLOSE');
    door.status = 'open';
  } else {
    $(this).text('OPEN');
    door.status = 'closed';
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: '/led',
    method: 'GET',
    data: door,
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, What would the identified be to reference in `request.args.get`? Is it `status`?

Comment: @SpicyPat I don't use Flask, but I suspect what you have is correct. Since you were not passing the variable correctly to Flask, I suspect your code was not finding the `status`. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request

Comment: Looks like `request.args.get('status')` and `request.args['status']` should work. The `.get()` is used in case the index is missing, so I would stick with that.