# Encode/decode image to base64 flask&python

Tags: python, json, flask, base64

I have image that is called 'image.png', first off i make request to my server to save image as base64 string in json file.

```py
def get_img_content(coding='utf-8'):
    with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
        img_data = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode(coding)
        return img_data

requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?face={get_img_content()}')
```

Bellow i've added server's code which handle my request

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

if "data.json" not in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    with open('data.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        pass
    content = {'ids': [], 'results': []}
else:
    with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        content = json.loads(f.read())

def add_id(id, face, content=content):
    content['ids'].append({id: face})
    with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(content))

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    face = request.args.get('face')
    if not face:
        return 'Valid request has to contain face'
    id = [int(list(i.keys())[0]) for i in content['ids']]
    id = str(max(id) + 1 if id else 1)
    add_id(id, face)
    print(content)
    return id


@app.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
def get():
    id = request.args.get('id')
    if not id:
        return 'Valid request has to contain id'
    for i in content['results']:
        if list(i.keys())[0] == id:
            return json.dumps({'result': i[id]})
    return "Couldn't find result"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

After that i tried to read this base64 string from data.json and convert it to image, but i got PaddingError
**binascii.Error: Incorrect padding**

```py
import base64
import json

with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = json.loads(f.read())


def to_image():
    with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(list(content['ids'][0].items())[-1][-1].encode('utf-8')))


to_image()
```

Please help me to reproduce my steps without this error.

Comment: For what you doing the decoding a b64 string into utf-8?

Comment: @Evgeniy, to get string and write it to data.json through flask. base64.   b64encode returns bytes.

Comment: Each format has their own "header" and "ending" (i think) in order to know what type of information it contain, where the data start and where it end.

I debugged your code, the arrays of bytes that you write in data.json are much less than the original array of bytes from the image... you are loosing information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INTRODUCTION**

Each format has (should have) their own "header" and "ending" signal in order to know:

1. what type of information it contain
2. where the data start.
3. where it end.

See the "header" and "ending" structure for .jpg files here: [JPG Signature Format: Documentation & Recovery Example](https://www.file-recovery.com/jpg-signature-format.htm)

Why that exist? It prevent, exactly what happen here... there should be a "hidden" code that check if the "header" and the "ending" bytes are right, if they don't, then the data have lost. Then alert to you with:

> binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

**DEBUG**

The arrays of bytes that you write in data.json are much less than the original array of bytes from the image... you are losing information.

**OBSERVATION**

What i see and i thing the problem is, is that you are sending a large data with HTTP verb GET. It has 8KB limit capacity. then if you image is larger than that you can't send it with GET request.

See the limit here: [Maximum length of HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

**RECOMMENDATION**

For this case, use POST request to send data larger than 8KB (*the use of POST request is not limited only because the size, there are other cases too)

**SOLUTION**

There are multiple ways to send that with POST request, see here: [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types).

To send:

1. **one** image, use the MIME type `image`
2. multiples files with `multipart/form-data`
3. you could send JSON with `application/json`
4. send raw text with `text/plain`

See: [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request#:%7E:text=The%20format%20of%20an%20HTTP,value%20pairs%20in%20the%20body.&text=You%20can%20see%20this%20using,being%20sent%20across%20the%20wire.)

> **Image:** Image or graphical data including both bitmap and vector still images as well as animated versions of still image formats such as animated GIF or APNG. Common examples are image/jpeg, image/png, and image/svg+xml.

You can take the data, this way (I think, this is only for multiple files `multipart/form-data`):

```
face=request.files['face'].read()
```

Maybe the others are:

```
request.form['face']
request.data['face']
request.get_data['face']
request.get_json['face']
```

Here are the correct and differents ways to receive the data from POST request: [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)

See additional:[Flask HTTP methods, handle GET & POST requests](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods/)

Comment: if i change requests.get to requests.post, will it resolve my problem?

Comment: Anyway i'll try

Comment: That doesn't work. I also got PaddingError. Should i use requests.post(url, params={'face':get_img_content()}) instead of requests.post('http://127:0:0:1:5000/?face={get_img_content()}')?

Comment: If you put the data inside the url, then you are using GET request