# How to send a POST request to Flask API using Fetch in a React app

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, fetch-api

To demonstrate my problem, I have made a simple example

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

    function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/get')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/post', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request' })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request' })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  }, []);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

In first `useEffect` hook, I am sending a `GET` request to my flask API and logging the response of request.

In second `useEffect` hook, I am sending a `POST` request to my flask API and logging the response of request.

In third`useEffect` hook, I am sending a `POST` request to [jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) and logging the response of request.

first `useEffect` output:
[image]

second `useEffect` output:
[image]

third `useEffect` output:
[image]

I am using the same post request code for request for my Flask API and [jsonplaceholder.typicode.com](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) API but response of my API is always empty object `{}`. Which is not expected. It should return this `{ title: 'React POST Request' }` object. I try to find the solution but nothing work for me.

My simple Flask API:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
def get():
   return { "title": 'React GET Request' }

@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
   return request.args
```

`.flaskenv file`:

```
FLASK_APP=api.py
FLASK_ENV=development
```

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "flask-app-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

By the way, I am using `create-react-app` package to setup my React App.

Comment: try sending jsonify object from api end,  `from flask import Josnify ` then return as `return jsonify(data)`

Comment: have you seen: [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434599), `request.args` looks like the key to use when you are sending data in the query string, and not in the request _body_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. That's because `request.args` is exactly that.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=request%20args#flask.Request.args

> The parsed URL parameters (the part in the URL after the question mark).

`request.args` are querystring parameters, and you are supplying no querystring parameters in your `POST`.

I'm rusty on flask, but the docs say `request.json` would return your json encoded post.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=request%20json#flask.Request.json