# Flask + Requests erroring "TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am using Flask and the requests module to send a post request to an external server, and it keeps giving me "TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable".
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\project\main.py", line 22, in send_ban
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:5001/upload/ban', data=request, timeout=5)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 469, in send
    for i in request.body:
  File "F:\Pembroke Website\adminpanel\auth\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 378, in <lambda>
    __iter__ = lambda x: iter(x._get_current_object())
TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable
```

The code it tracebacks to:

```py
@main.route('/send/ban', methods=['POST'])
def send_ban():
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:5001/upload/ban', data=request, timeout=5) # This is the traceback line
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        if not r.text.find('Uploaded'):
            flash('Successfully Banned User', 'primary')
            return redirect('/ban')
    elif r.status_code == 404:
        flash('Unable to ban user, server appears to be offline', 'danger')
        return redirect('/ban')
    elif r.status_code == 500:
        flash('Unable to ban user, server appears to be having issues', 'danger')
        return redirect('/ban')
```

I am running this on a venv.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name `data=request` to something different, i.e. `data=data`?

Comment: That wouldnt work because I am sending the same data out as I got in with the post request.

Comment: Could you rename the variable i.e `request=data;requests.post...data=data...`

Comment: No, the variable is permanently named with Flask. https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods/

Comment: You can still give the variable another name however I have spotted an error: `data=requests;requests.post...data=data`. You are effectively creating a variable equal to that

Comment: That didnt work at all... It is still saying the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would image the issue you are having is because you are passing a Request object to a value which should be a dictionary.

You need to extract your Flask request data from the Request object, place this in a Python dictionary and send this off to you endpoint.

I do not understand Flask fully but the main answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request) would suggest using data = request.form, assuming your POST request is from a HTML form post.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know how I could go about turning the request data into a dictionary?

Comment: Have you tried to use "data = request.form"? Based on the link it should work as long as your data is coming from a HTML form.