# Error: Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Disclaimer re potential duplicates: There have been similar questions to mine and I think I have read pretty much all of those answers by now but none of them solved the issue for me.

I've got an app, frontend is React, and backend is a flask server. I'm having a major issue. The code seems to check out for both front- and backend, but after I click the submit button of a form, I get the error in the JS console: `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected.`

Now, there is only one button on my Form, and this is of type `submit`, with the `handleSubmit` handler in the `form` tag, so I don't think this is causing the issue.
I also added this config object to handle potential CORS faults but I'm not getting any CORS errors at least.

**React Form Component code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import DisplayUpper from "./DisplayUpper";

function Form() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState("");
  const [isSubmitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    setSubmitted(true);

    console.log("button clicked");

    const config = {
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    };

    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:5000/process",
        {
          inputText: inputText,
        },
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("res", res);
        setFetchedData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((er) => {
        console.log(er);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
        <label>
          Enter Text :
          <TextField
            multiline={true}
            variant="outlined"
            name="inputText"
            value={inputText}
            onChange={(e) => setInputText(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" name="Submit">
          SUBMIT
        </Button>
      </form>
      {isSubmitted && <DisplayUpper />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

**Then, the app.py code:**

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    text = request.form.get('inputText')
    upper_text = text.upper()
    print(upper_text)
    return upper_text
```

I set proxy: "http://localhost:5000" in package.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser is attempting to submit your form to the current URL via the method on the form when the button of `type="submit"` inside it is being clicked.

Note: if you don't set a `type` attribute on your `<button>`, [the default value of `submit` will be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#type).

As you are handling the form submission with javascript, you should prevent the form's default behaviour:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Changing the button type to button means that when I hit submit, nothing happens. I added e.preventDefault(); also and this error goes away, so that is cool - thank you. However, the value is not rendered, I get internal server error in JS console, and AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper' in terminal. Any thoughts?

Comment: @timman: Your error is in the python backend. You asked a question tagged javascript. If you need help debugging the flask app, post a new question.

Comment: yep, will do. thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: Looks like your form is now submitting correctly. I agree with @HåkenLid. I would ask a new question about how to handle the request and extract data on the server end tagged with `python` & `flask`.

Comment: You could try changing `request.form` to `request.json` or make axios post form data instead of json.

Comment: Nice answer here for Geting the data received in a Flask request https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/5385381

Answer (score 4):

I got this warning when I had a button inside a form tag - the button click handler navigated away from the page

The default behaviour for a button inside a form is type="submit"

The warning disappeared when I changed the button to type="button"

In my case, I did not want the button to submit the form anyway - Otherwise if the button is meant to submit the form then use @ksav's answer

Comment: I had to specify the type as button even though I was using a button element. e.g., `<button type="button">my button triggering the form warning</button>`