# Form submission canceled because the form is not connected-react, express, node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, try-catch, nodemailer

the chrome console returned this error *"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"* on hitting the submit button, though nothing was returned in the IDE terminal. The react form is connected to a node js backend using express, nodemailer,cors, google api, dotenv and google-auth-library

```js
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
const REDIRECT_URI = process.env.REDIRECT_URI
const REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI)
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token:REFRESH_TOKEN})

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())


app.post("/send_mail", cors(), async (req, res) => {

    const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  try{
    const accessToken = await OAuth2Client.getAccessToken()
    

    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'example.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            user: process.env.USERNAME,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
            accessToken: accessToken

        }
    })

    await transport.sendMail({
        from: '"example Contact" <contact@example.com>',
        to: 'hey@gmail.com',
        subject: "test email",
        html: output
        
    })
} catch (error) {
    return error
}
    
})


app.listen(7000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

```html
export default function ContactForm() {
  const [ sent, setSent ] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSend = async (e) => {
        setSent(true)
        try {
            await axios.post("http://localhost:7000/send_mail", {
                name, email, message
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }



  return (
    <>
        {!sent ? (
      <FormStyle onSubmit={handleSend}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name">
            Your Name
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              name="name"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">
            Your Email
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="message">
            Your message
            <textarea
              type="text"
              id="message"
              name="message"
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" >Send</button>
      </FormStyle>
        ) : (
          
<MailSentAnimation />
          
          )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327333/error-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected

Comment: in my case, it is `handleSend` and adding the prevent default method, my code looks like this `const handleSend = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); ...}`. The error cleared in the console though the form still doesn't actually submit. Not sure what to do next but if it's of any importance, the server at `localhost:7000` returns a **cannot Get/**

Comment: When you just try GET `localhost:7000`, it will not work because you don't have that route (`/`) defined. And your POST `/send_mail` route doesn't do anything with `res`. Do at least `res.send('ok')` or something like that after `sendMail`.

Comment: I have effected all you suggested in the code. Added `app.get('/', cors(), async (req, res) =>{ res.send("this is working")` and `res.send('ok')` into the code. No error is being returned and `localhost:7000` now returns **this is working** . Yet, the messages are still not sent. I thought it was maybe because it was running on my local machine so i deployed it, but its still the same outcome.

Comment: I think I might have found a problem but I'm not sure how to solve it. I switched the google API service to Mailtrap instead to test code. It basically presented the same problem, no error returned but it doesn't actually send any message. So I used the credentials directly instead of passing it through dotenv and it worked. Not sure what to do because dotenv is already required in the code.