# How to send AND receive POST requests with JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, python, flask

So I have been searching for some time and have been wondering. How can I add javascript that sends POST data to an external site and how can I make that external site receive it?

I tried

```js
    <script>
    let data = {element: "barium"};
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/newCheckout", {
      method: "POST", 
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => {
      console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
    });
    </script>
```

and received it with (Python/Flask): element = request.form.get('element')
did not work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't receive POST requests with javascript in a browser (i.e. and HTML) - you can receive the result of the post request ... what error are you seeing in the broswer developer tools console?

Comment: You need to enable CORS.

Comment: @JaromandaX I want to receive the result it is what I meant so how?

Comment: what are you receiving now? check the browser *developer* tools console to see what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending JSON data but trying to retrieve form data in flask. Try using `request.json()` in flask instead (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request) on how to receive different data-types in flask).

You may have to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` in javascript for that to work. For example:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:5000/newCheckout", {
  method: "POST", 
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
});
```

---

Some more details of what's going on

JSON looks like this: `{"x": 1, "y": 2}`
form-encoded data looks like this: `x=1&y=2`
When you send data to a server, you're just sending it a string of characters. You can send anything in that string, but if you're sending a common format, like JSON, or form-encoded data, you will generally set the `Content-Type` header too, so the server knows what kind of data it's receiving (This is important, because sometimes a server will support multiple data types).

Flask will inspect the Content-Type header, and parse the data accordingly. They chose to place the resulting data in different locations on the request object depending on the type of data being sent, so you have to make sure you look in the right places to get the desired data.

Right now, you've coded it up so that the client will send a chunk of plain text (you didn't send any specific content-type), and the server is expecting form-encoded data.

Comment: Thanks!

For some reason request.json or request.json() did not work, BUT request.get_json(force=True) did! Thanks again!

Comment: @Oze - that's probably because the server wasn't receiving the Content-type header - maybe it wasn't getting set correctly on the client? Either way, glad you were able to find a solution.