# $.ajax error: function doesn't return the error message from Flask only INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

In Flask I return simple JSON string like this, in case of error:

the Exception coming from this :

```
   try:
     
     self.data.add('data', self.request.data)
     
    except Exception as err:     
       print(traceback.format_exc())
       return _build_response_json()
```

The `_build_response_json()` function return string JSON as shown below:

Getting this exception/Traceback:

```
  Unable to display children:Error resolving variables Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\app\base.py", line 73, in get_name
    self.data.add('data', self.request.data)
AttributeError: 'ObjRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_resolver.py", line 213, in resolve
    return dict[key]
KeyError: 'Exception'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1195, in do_it
    _typeName, val_dict = pydevd_vars.resolve_compound_variable_fields(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.scope, self.attributes)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 281, in resolve_compound_variable_fields
    var = getVariable(thread_id, frame_id, scope, attrs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 239, in getVariable
    var = resolver.resolve(var, k)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_resolver.py", line 215, in resolve
    return getattr(dict, key)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Exception'
```

The JSON:

```
def _build_response_json()
       retur_json = {
            "status": "error",
            "title": "error",
            "message": "this is error massage from server",
            "type": "error",
            "status": 500,
            "id": "xxxxxi"
        }
        
        
    json_str = json.dumps(retur_json)
    return json_str
```

but in the client side when error I keep getting:

```
res.status = 500  
error = INTERNAL SERVER ERROR  
options = error
```

Code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/execute",
            data: data,
            success: function (res) {
               ....
            },
            error: function (res, options, error) {
                                 
                console.log(res.status);
                console.log(error);
                console.log(options);
            }
        });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the trace back of the error message on the flask app? If there is no traceback, you have to set debugging to true.

Comment: im running in debug mode , how can i see the traceback?

Comment: It should be in the terminal that you run `flask run`

Comment: i updated my question with the traceback

Comment: That looks like you are trying to write a custom wrapper around flask? For a pure flask, access request data can just be `request.data` where `request` is from `from flask import request` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/10163723 for more detail. If you cannot use that we will need to see how `ObjectifyRequest` is declared, and how you pass the data to it.

Comment: But the thing as i understand it it go to the exception ,and the exception build the json string to return back just fine , but somewhere from the return to the client the json got lost

Comment: Huh, interesting. Can you give us full traceback then? Like everything

Comment: That looks like error in pycharm. If you run it without pycharm or without debugging it in pycharm does the problem still there? And by debug mode I mentioned in the first comment I mean the debug mode of flask which is to set `debug=True` for `app.run(debug=True)` and not to run the flask application with a debugger.