# How can I send a XML from HTML in string to Python (using Flask) using Fetch API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, xml, flask

I'm designing an app that receives an XML file from an HTML page and send it to Python using Flask
**This is my HTML (frontend) code**

```html
<input type="file" id="files"  class="form-control" accept=".xml" required />
<button onclick="send()" style="width: 150px;" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

And I am using Flask with Python to run my backend, I am using POSTMAN (i show it below) and I send an XML on it and return what is supposed to return
**This is my Python code**

```
@app.route('/Students', methods=['POST'])
def loaddata():
    # this is a list 
    global dataArray

    entry= request.data.decode('utf-8')

    xmlentry= ET.fromstring(entry)

    for student in xmlentry.findall('STUDENT'):
        name= dte.find('NAME').text
        address = dte.find('ADDRESS').text
        new = DataObject(name,adress)

        # DataObject its a class, i am using OOP
        dataArray.append(new)


    return jsonify({'Mensaje':'Students added to the database',})
```

but I don't know how to send the XML data from the HTML file and make it work with my Python Backend, I have used Fetch before but no for this particular case **This is my JavaScript code where I have confusion**

```js
var file1 = document.getElementById("file");

function send() {

fetch('localhost:3000/Students', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: file1,
            headers:{
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
                console.error('Error:', err)
                alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
        })
        .then(response =>{
          console.log(response);
          alert(response.Mensaje)
        })
    }
```

What I can do?
[This is my program tested with POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BegZJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you already have the XML inside `file1`? Or do you relay on the User to enter a File into a Input element?

Comment: Also, I see `var file1 = document.getElementById("file")` and in your HTML, I see `<input type="file" id="files"  class="form-control" accept=".xml" required />`, so this would not match up, `file != files`

Comment: The user its going to put the XML in the input element

Comment: Also thanks for the HTML aclaration

Comment: Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following HTML / JavaScript.

```js
function send(file) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('xmlFile', file);
  fetch('localhost:3000/Students', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error:', err)
      alert("Ocurrio un error, ver la consola")
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      alert(response.Mensaje)
    })
}

var fileInp = document.getElementById("files");
var sendBtn = document.getElementById("filesBtn");
sendBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (fileInp.files[0] !== undefined) {
    send(fileInp.files[0]);
  } else {
    alert("Please select a XML File.");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" class="form-control" accept=".xml" required />
<button id="filesBtn" style="width: 150px;" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

This is based on the following Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file

When the User clicks Send, the `file` is sent to the function. New Form Data is created and POST to the server.

You may need to adjust your Python. See here: [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)

Comment: i have been trying the solution, the fetch API looks that its working fine, but i think my error comes from Python, am using the next lines with the for loop show before:

entry = request.form['formData']

xmlentry = ET.fromstring(entry)

But i got an error from the fetch try catch and this errors in console
'Error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource'

'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response is undefined'