# how to access keys in a rquest sent via POST method

Tags: python, flask

in the below posted webservice, i obtain the data posted from the front-end using `json.loads` the result of the print statment is posted below in the sample-data section.
the problem i have is when i try to obtain the values included in the `request.data`, for example, `treatmentGeometryAsJSONInEPSG3857`. the error i am getting when i run the code is:

```
treatmentAsGeoJSONInEPSG3857 = json.loads(request.data)['body'][config['FRONT_END_KEYS']['key_treatmentGeometryAsJSONInEPSG3857']]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

please let me know how to access the contents of the posted request

i referred to the following posts as well but none contains an answer to my question

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask-de
```

**code**:

```
@app.route("/experimentExistenceCheck/", methods=['POST','OPTIONS'])
    def experimentExistenceCheck():
    preFlight = FlaskAccessControlUtils.preFlightCheck(request)
    if preFlight: return preFlight
    
    data = json.loads(request.data)['body']
    print("--------->",data)
    
    treatmentAsGeoJSONInEPSG3857 = json.loads(request.data)['body'][config['FRONT_END_KEYS']['key_treatmentGeometryAsJSONInEPSG3857']]
    selectedSiteId = json.loads(request.data)['body'][config['FRONT_END_KEYS']['selectedSiteID']]
    threshold = json.loads(request.data)['body'][config['FRONT_END_KEYS']['threshold']]
    visualizationOperationID = json.loads(request.data)['body'][config['FRONT_END_KEYS']['visualizationOperationID']]
    print("--------->",treatmentAsGeoJSONInEPSG3857)
    print("--------->",selectedSiteId)
    print("--------->",threshold)
    print("--------->",visualizationOperationID)
```

**sample data**:

```
{"threshold":"1","visualizationOperationID":2,"treatmentGeometryAsJSONInEPSG3857":"{\"coordinates\":[[[745037.9841857546,6644742.79192291],[744938.5789015774,6644804.979114908],[744973.912533394,6644856.330659814],[745025.2640783006,6644838.428286361],[745022.4373877553,6644802.623539453],[744997.9394030292,6644768.703252909],[745037.9841857546,6644742.79192291]]],\"type\":\"Polygon\"}","selectedSiteID":"202108041239"}
```

Comment: When sending the request, do you know if the request body is specified as 'data' or 'json'?

Comment: @BenZikri i am not using JSON.stringify