# Retrieving data from a combined multidict in python

Tags: python, json, flask

This is my first time asking a question on this platform.

I currently have a camera set up that we are using for people counting. I am using a push function on the camera to push the data I need to a https url (I am just using local host on my pc). I am getting a response but the response is coming in as what seems to be a `CombinedMultiDict` which is nothing like the JSON payload documented/expected. Does anyone know how I can pull the "In" and "Out" variables so that I can further work with these variables.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict

app = Flask(__**name**__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])

def home():
       print(request.values)
       return "Camera"

app.run(host='localhost', port=777)
```

and once the camera pushes this is the response I get when I print `request.values`:

```
CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([('{"Source":{"ReportTime":"2022-03-25T16:02:12Z","GroupID":"Group 01","DeviceID":"","ModelName":"SC9133","MacAddress":"00:02:D1:99:DB:13","IPAddress":"192.168.147.172","TimeZone":" 2","DST":"0"},"Data":[{"RuleType":"Counting","CountingInfo":[{"EndTime":"2022-03-25T15:54:00Z","In":0,"Out":0,"StartTime":"2022-03-25T15:53:00Z","RuleName":"Rule-1"}]}]}', '')])])
```

So I am seeing the in and out variable but I would like to isolate these variables in there own variable if that makes sense. I know this is going to be hard to test as this is a local camera but any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `request.form` to specifically get the data. [request.values](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=combinedmultidict#flask.Request.values) returns both `request.form` and `request.args`. [This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/13577373) covers this well.

If you proceed with `request.form`, here's one way you can achieve your goal:

```py
import json

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    content = request.form  # ImmutableMultiDict(text, "")
    text = list(content.keys())[0]  # '{"Source":{"ReportTime":"2022-...
    json_content = json.loads(text)
    print(json_content["Data"][0]["CountingInfo"][0])
    return "Camera"
```

Output:

```
{'EndTime': '2022-03-25T15:54:00Z',
 'In': 0,
 'Out': 0,
 'StartTime': '2022-03-25T15:53:00Z',
 'RuleName': 'Rule-1'}
```