# Cloud Run: Why does python flask return 400 Bad request? But locally everything is fine

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a simple flask application. And I need to run it on Cloud Run with enabled option "Manage authorized users with Cloud IAM."

app.py

```
from flask import Flask

api_app = Flask(__name__)
```

endpoints.py

```
from app import api_app

@api_app.route("/create", methods=["POST"])
def api_create():
    # logic
```

main.py

```
from app import api_app
from endpoints import *    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

And it works if i run it locally. It also works well if run in docker. When I upload the application image to Cloud Run, there are no deployment errors. But when I try to call the endpoint I get an error even though everything is working fine locally.

Request example:

```
import urllib
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
import requests
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "test.json"

audience="https://test-service-*****.a.run.app"

req = urllib.request.Request(audience)
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)

response = requests.post(f"{audience}/create", data={
    "text": "cool text"
}, headers={
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
})
```

Response:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

In Cloud Run logs I have only one warning log
`POST 400 820b 3ms python-requests/2.26.0 https://test-service-*****.a.run.app/create`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /alpha
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:api_app
```

Why can't I reach the application endpoint in Cloud Run?

Comment: You should really look at the [Cloud Run logs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging) and see what they say...

Comment: @EdoAkse sorry, its typo in question

Comment: @EdoAkse I looked. Error 400 duplicated in logs. Nothing to indicate an error

Comment: and no errors between the latest deployment and the 400s?

Comment: @EdoAkse no errors. As I said, the same version works fine locally, but I can't access the endpoints in Cloud Run for the same version.

Comment: What's the `endpoint` variable value? Shouldn't be audience?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry, typo

Comment: There is no need to set "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" and include a JSON service account key in your container. Instead, just use the --service-account option when you deploy your Cloud Run service with 
"gcloud run deploy". One less thing that can go wrong, and your container won't include a dangerous service account key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some testing, and the only thing I did was remove the port binding from the Dockerfile `CMD exec gunicorn` and from the `main.py`. Note that the dundermain thingy is not needed as gunicorn takes care of that.

After that it worked as expected.

Note that I did not set it up as a private endpoint as I was to lazy to jump through the hoops for that, and the response code you get back is not a 403.

Note that I also made sure that `/create` returned something. I'm going to assume that you did the same.

---

**EDIT**

I've made the CR endpoint private, and created a serviceaccount with the role "Cloud Run Invoker", created a JSON key and saved it as `test.json`

I've also added some logic to print out the token, and to decode the first part. Your output should look similar to mine.

---

**EDIT 2**

In the end it ended up Flask not being able to deal with the incoming data. There's a very [nice answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53567917/9267296) which explains how to get the data from all the different ways it can get POSTed

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /alpha
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn  --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:api_app
```

**endpoints.py**

```py
from app import api_app
from flask import request


@api_app.route("/create", methods=["POST"])
def api_create():
    data = request.data
    return f"{data}"
```

**main.py**

```py
from app import api_app
from endpoints import *
```

**perform_request.py**

```py
import urllib
import requests
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
import os
import base64


os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "test.json"
target_uri = "https://pasta*****.a.run.app"


req = urllib.request.Request(target_uri)
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, target_uri)

print(token, "\n")
print(base64.b64decode(f"""{token.split(".")[0]}==""".encode("utf-8")), "\n")


response = requests.post(
    f"{target_uri}/create",
    data={"text": "cool text"},
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"},
)

print(response.text)
```

**output**

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIm[SNIPPED]

b'{"alg":"RS256","kid":"713fd68c9[SNIPPED]","typ":"JWT"}' 

b'text=cool+text'
```

Comment: Alas, I see the same error. I also changed dockerfile to ```CMD exec gunicorn --bind :443 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:api_app```

Comment: are you actually using waitress in your deployed app?

Comment: Cloud Run does not support applications that listen on anything but HTTP. Your suggestion will **not** work for a Cloud Run application. The Cloud Run Frontend (GFE) proxies public HTTPS to internal HTTP. SSL is offloaded.

Comment: @EdoAkse yes, I use waitress in deployed app

Comment: you know both `gunicorn` and `waitress` are WSGI servers? You're using WSGI server to run another WSGI server. I would definitely remove `waitress` from your code, and just use `gunicorn` in your Dockerfile

Comment: @EdoAkse Yes, I know. I have already tried to use ```waitress``` only - with no result. I have only used ```gunicorn``` with no results. Using them together didn't change anything either. Anyway I see the same error.

Comment: @EdoAkse I clarified the question, maybe I missed important details trying to simplify the example. Thanks for your time and willingness to help

Comment: Check my updated answer, it's simpler than you think

Comment: @EdoAkse Alas. The error seems to be related to the way requests are sent, and not to the service itself.

Comment: let me try again on a private endpoint then

Comment: @EdoAkse I did some tests. `GET` requests work fine with "Cloud IAM" enabled and when it's disabled. The problem is only in the `POST`. Maybe something is wrong with the headers... I continue to test

Comment: so, either there's something wrong with the token, or with the actual code that is in the `/create` endpoint. You can try to create a simplistic endpoint just as I did to determine if it's the code running in it

Comment: @EdoAkse Thanks for the good example. I completed it using `Content-type: application/json` in requests and it helped me solve the problem. Thanks again for your help and time

Comment: Please be aware that there are a lot of ways to pass data with a POST. There's a SO post with 23 answers on how to get data in Flask, all valid. [Linky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)